# PHP Maths Equation Function

Tags: php, math

What i am really looking for is a maths equation function that takes in a string representing and equation and calculates the answer as a return type

For Example 
"(((4 * 5) + 6) * 2) / 8"

OutPut: 6.5

So in coding tearms something like

```
print calc("(((4 * 5) + 6) * 2) / 8");
```

Is there already a class or a function that some angel has built or do i gota do it my self

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As cloudhead said, just fixed up.

```
$nums = "(((4 * 5) + 6) * 2) / 8";
eval("\$nums = $nums;");
echo $nums;
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use `eval()` for that, it'll evaluate the argument as php code:

```
$result = eval("(((4 * 5) + 6) * 2) / 8"); // 6.5
print $result;
```

Comment: I literally copies and pasted to make sure but it says

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/test.php(12) : eval()'d code on line 1

Comment: ah yea sorry about that, you should assign it to a variable, gonna edit the answer.

Comment: Try this one: eval("\$test = (((4 * 5) + 6) * 2) / 8;"); print $test; The backslash before $test is important!

Comment: Just an additional note: Please be aware that user input not sanitized will lead to problems!

Comment: need another edit on that, the one that worked was

eval("\$test = (((4 * 5) + 6) * 2) / 8;");
print $test;

as merkuro suggested

Answer (score 2):

If you end up rolling your own, read [Smart design of a math parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114586/smart-design-of-a-math-parser) or [Equation expression parser with precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256/equation-expression-parser-with-precedence). With explicit parentheses as in your example the parser would be much simpler.