# PHP calculation based on the array values

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to create a calculation based on the values of the array - imagine the following array:

```
$values = array(9, +, 10, *, 7)
```

I thought about the following approach:

```
$result = number_format(implode(' ', $values), 2)
```

but this obviously doesn't work.

Any idea how could this be achieved?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Maths Equation Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046424/php-maths-equation-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `eval()`...

```
eval('$result = ' . implode($values) . ';');
```

If any portion of this array came from user input, you should filter the array to ensure it only has numbers and valid operators.

```
$safeValues = array_filter($values, function($value) {
    return is_numeric($value) OR in_array($value, array('+', '-', '/', '*'));
});
```

Comment: agreed, although depending on your hosting this may be restricted. If you can't use the eval method, you're likely going to need to create a math parser, or find a library that will do so

Comment: or something like eval('$result = ' . implode($values) . ';'); since eval returns null usually.. and the expression does not return something, so you need to assign the result in the variable inside the eval call

Comment: @mishu Thanks, I haven't used PHP in a little while :)

Comment: @alex you are welcome.. it was just a small note, I think everyone got the idea.. as this one: you might want to add a semicolon also at the end of the line (just after implode) :)

Comment: @mishu I'm hopeless tonight :P Thanks.