# Chrome App: Doing maths from a string

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I have a basic Chrome App that I'm building that constructs strings like this:

```
"1 + 4 - 3 + -2"
```

Seeing as you can't use `eval()` in Chrome Apps, how can I get the answer to a string like so?

eg. If this was just a normal webpage I would use something like this:

```
var question = {
  text: "1 + 4 - 3 + -2",
  answer: eval(this.text)
}
```

Is there any possible way of replacing `eval()` with something else to answer a string like `question.text`?

Comment: @JSelser A link, please?

Comment: Here's a question which accepted answer has enough links to spin your head for days. The shunting yard algorithm is an automaton: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114586/smart-design-of-a-math-parser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try modifying string to

```
"+1 +4 -3 -2"
```

utilizing `String.prototype.split()` , `Array.prototype.reduce()` , `Number()`

```js
var question = {
  text: "+1 +4 -3 -2",
  answer: function() {
            return this.text.split(" ")
                   .reduce(function(n, m) {
                     return Number(n) + Number(m)
                   })
          }
};

console.log(question.answer())
```

Comment: Of course! Didn't think about using an array. I guess I could expand upon that method to support other kinds of math strings. Thanks.

Comment: Brilliant solution. Seriously doubt you can expand it to support different operators though.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
var question = {
  text: "1 + 4 - 3 + -2",
  answer: eval(ans(question.text))
}
console.log('Text : '+question.text);
console.log('answer : '+question.answer);
```

*Used String replace method*

```
function ans(str){
var s = str.replace(/\s/g, '')
console.log('S : '+s);
return s;
}
```

Comment: That method simply removes whitespace and evaluates it using `eval`. What I'm asking for is a method to replace `eval` entirely.

Comment: test the input "1 + 4 - 3 + -2" you given with above function it splits but the result is NAN.

Comment: If you mean the other answer, yes, but it can be changed to support the string I provided. The other answer isn't an in depth solution, as what I've asked for may prove difficult, but merely an idea for how to do it.