# Convert string to expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, expression

I am making a calculator in JavaScript and I want to know how to turn a string into an expression.

```
var numbers = "5+5+6";
numbers = +numbers;
 document.querySelector('.screen').innerHTML = numbers;
```

Adding + before the variable does not seem to work. I would appreciate it if someone helped.

Comment: use the eval() function

Comment: Eval is what you are looking for, but you should know its use is generally frowned upon. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [eval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) function like this:

```
var numbers = "5+5+6";
document.querySelector('.screen').innerHTML = eval(numbers);;
```

Evaluate/Execute JavaScript code/expressions:

```
var x = 10;
var y = 20;
var a = eval("x * y") + "<br>";
var b = eval("2 + 2") + "<br>";
var c = eval("x + 17") + "<br>";

var res = a + b + c;
```

The result of res will be:

```
200
4
27
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using eval, which is cheating - you could always write a simple calculator app.

First, take advantage of String.split() as follows

```
var numbers = "5+5+6";

numbers.split("");
// => ["5","+","5","+","6"]
```

Now all you need to do is figure out how to evaluate it while keeping the order of operations correct.  Hint: it might involve trees.

Comment: First of all, saying it *might* involve trees isn't really a hint and secondly it doesn't even need trees. The OP should know that he needs to convert this `infix` notation to `postfix` and then use a postfix evaluation algorithm to perform the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `String.prototype.match()` , `Array.prototype.reduce()` , `Number()` . See also [Chrome App: Doing maths from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32982719/chrome-app-doing-maths-from-a-string)

```js
var numbers = "5+5+6";
var number = numbers.match(/\d+|\+\d+|\-\d+/g)
  .reduce(function(a, b) {
    return Number(a) + Number(b)
  });
document.querySelector(".screen").innerHTML = number;
```

```html
<div class="screen"></div>
```