# eval is not calculate if zero before the number

Tags: javascript

```js
var values = ["50.00024+40.04005+0.1", "0050.00024+040.04005+0.1"];

for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
  if(values[i].indexOf('+')>0 || values[i].indexOf('-')>0 || values[i].indexOf('*')>0 || values[i].indexOf('/')>0){
    try{
      var evaluated = eval(values[i]);
      if(typeof evaluated === 'number'){
        console.log(evaluated);
      }
    }catch (e){
      console.error(e)
    }
  }
}
```

I have some math actions, it's could be plus, minus or other actions, and I need to take result for this actions. I use eval for this. But if I have zero before number like 005,75 eval is not working. How can I calculate this?

Comment: Don't use eval... Split the strings on the allowed operations, convert the numbers to actual numbers and then compute the result.

Comment: I was thinking about it, but eval is short way.. perhaps you are right. short way is not allways better

Comment: A zero in front of a number in Javascript is Octal notation.  eg. `var a = 010` = 8

Comment: @Keith bearing in mind parseInt("010") returns 10

Comment: @GeorgeCampbell  That's because parseInt has a default radix of 10.. And he's not using parseInt.

Comment: I suggest using https://stackoverflow.com/a/14990194/5674976

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the strings and parse the numbers, and then make them into a string again to use `eval`

```js
var values = ["50.00024+40.04005+0.1", "0050.00024+040.04005+0.1"];
values.forEach(function(value){
    var newValue = value.split(/([\+\-\*\/])/).map(a => parseFloat(a) || a).join('');
    var evaluated = eval(newValue);
    console.log(value,"==", evaluated);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There are various libraries like [math.js](http://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html) that can be used to evaluate expressions:

```js
console.log(math.eval("0050.00024+040.04005+0.1"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.16.5/math.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is probably the more secure answer

Answer (score 0):

you should convert it to float (ex. parseFloat("005.75") = 5.75 instead of evaluating strings

Answer (score -1):

Given code at Question you can use `.match()` to get number values, `.map()` and `.reduce()` to add the values

```js
var values = ["50.00024+40.04005+0.1", "0050.00024+040.04005+0.1"];

var res = values.map(function(n) {
  return n.match(/[\d.]+/g).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + Number(b)
  }, 0)
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Looking at this line `values[i].indexOf('+')>0 || values[i].indexOf('-')>0 || values[i].indexOf('*')>0 || values[i].indexOf('/')>0` the questioner is expecting other operators too.

Comment: @shawon191 The same approach can be used where the operator is matched using `RegExp` `/[-+*][\d.]+/g`, see also [Chrome App: Doing maths from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32982719/chrome-app-doing-maths-from-a-string)

Comment: I think the linked answer won't help for `*` or `/`.

Comment: My answer does not omit the operators. `/([\+\-\*\/])/` notice the wrapping first brackets in the regex, which are used to prevent omitting the splitting symbol.