# How do I convert a string to number which have operator inside it?

Tags: javascript

I have a string which consist of a number with operators. Like : displayText ="123+12*23".And I want to convert it into number so that all the mathematical operations will be performed. Any idea how can I do that

Comment: You're looking for the [**`eval()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function.

Comment: You need to define all your operators and their precedence first as this determines the complexity of the possible solutions.

Comment: Read about [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). But be careful when using it (check if the string contains any harmful code before evaluating).

Comment: `eval()` is not necessary

Comment: See also [Chrome App: Doing maths from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32982719/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Function`

```js
let displayText = "123+12*23";

let num = str => new Function(`return ${str}`)();

console.log(num(displayText));
```

Comment: Still as unsafe as `eval()`

Comment: @Pablo What code is entirely not "unsafe"?

Comment: @Pablo: Not quite. It doesn't have access to the local scope the function is created in (it only has access to global scope).

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for here is the Javascript's native eval() function.

```
const displayText = "123+12*23";

const result = eval(displayText);
```

The above code will produce the result of the expression i.e. 399.

Comment: Three minutes ago same answer was given in comment section also no variation from the other answer