# How to parse & process mathematical expressions in JavaScript Calculator?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Whats the best approach with javascript to evaluate an expression like `3+1*sin(20)*e^3`?

First of all, I do not want to use built-in math-functions. In fact, I have already defined my own functions for `power`, `square root`, `sin`, `cos`, `exponential`, etc.

What I'm looking for, is a good way to parse an expression so I can pass them to these functions I created. I know there is an `eval()` function available in JavaScript for evaluating input expressions, but I'm not sure if that's suitable for this context.

Should I use `eval()`? If yes, how do I use it in this context? If no, what's a more suitable way to parse mathematical expressions?!
It's not an school assignment, its just a doubt.

Comment: `id` of `DOM` element should be unique; `keys` is set as `id` of multiple `input` elements at `html` at Question . _"Edit: I do not want to use inbuilt functions. How should I evaluate the expressions?"_ `Math.pow` appear to be used at `js` at Question at  `x = Math.pow(x,y);` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114586/smart-design-of-a-math-parser

Comment: "I do not want to use inbuilt functions. How should I evaluate the expressions?" — It sounds like you are really looking for a description of how to manually implement a sin lookup. That's more of a maths problem than it is a programming problem.

Comment: Your question is too broad, please make it more specific, what exactly is your problem when evaluating your problem ? And please only post relevant code and describe concrete problems.

Comment: I'm asking how to solve a expression not a sine function implementation.

Comment: Then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114586/smart-design-of-a-math-parser will help you

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be my real problem.

Comment: If you want to show us your code next time pls use https://jsfiddle.net/ so people can directly see what your existing code will produce.

Comment: Alright Sir, As I mentioned I'm new to stackoverflow. I'll take care it next time. Thanks again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluating a string as a mathematical expression in JavaScript](//stackoverflow.com/q/2276021/90527)

Answer (score 3):

## Using a third party library

In a real life situation, you'd want to use a library like [math.js](http://mathjs.org/) to do the calculations for you.

To use this library, first include it in your HTML:

```
 <script src='path/to/math.js'></script>
```

Then, you can just use the `math.eval` method to evaluate your expression :

```
math.eval('3+1*sin(20)*e^3');
```

That is, if `20` is a value expressed in radians. As it's probably a value expressed in degrees, you'd need to make this small adjustment:

```
math.eval('3+1*sin(20 deg)*e^3');
```

Because you explicitly said that you do not want to use the built-in math-functions, I suspect you're working on a school assignment. Note that **submitting school assignments on StackOverflow is frowned upon**, as it is considered a form of cheating.

But let's just ignore this and move on, shall we?!

---

## Doing it on your own

### Step 1: Calculation with built-in math functions

In real life projects you should ALWAYS use built-in math functions or third party libraries (like [math.js](http://mathjs.org/)) that use built-in math functions under the hood. That's because built-in math functions are both 100% reliable and performance optimized.

It's impossible to create your own equivalent of built-in math functions in a way that is both as reliable and as performance optimized as the built-in functions, so there is NEVER a good reason NOT to use the built-in functions. But since you explicitly asked for it, let's ignore that and look at how to do things WITHOUT the built-in math functions. I assume this also implied you do not want to use [math.js](http://mathjs.org/) or any other library.

Using JavaScript's built-in functions, you'd calculate your expression like this:

```
3+1*Math.sin(20)*Math.pow(Math.E,3)
```

Built-in functions used:

- [`Math.sin(x)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sin) can be used to calculate the `sin` of `x`
- [`Math.pow(x, n)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) can be used to calculate `xⁿ`
- [`Math.E()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/E) is a constant that represents `e`

Here, again, it's important to state this is true only if `20` is a value in radians. As `20` is probably a value in degrees, you probably want to define your own degree based sin function like this:

```
var dsin = function() {
  var piRatio = Math.PI / 180;
  return function dsin(degrees) {
    return Math.sin(degrees * piRatio);
  };
}();
```

Now, replace `Math.sin` with `dsin`:

```
3+1*dsin(20)*Math.pow(Math.E,3)
```

In any real world application, **this** would be the best was to calculate `3+1*sin(20)*e^3`!

### Step 2: Replacing built-in math functions with your own

Now, as you REALLY, REALLY, REALLY seem to want to go without built-in functions, just the next step is to replace every built-in function with a self-written equivalent. Often, there are multiple mathematical paths towards the same goal.

For example, you could write your `pow` function recursively like this:

```
var pow = function(base, exp) {
  if (exp == 0)
    return 1;
  else
    return base * power(base, exp - 1);
}
```

An iterative implementation:

```
var pow = function(base, exp) {
  var result = 1;
  while(exp--) {
    result *= base;
  }
  return result;
}
```

So now what, you ask?! How can you implement `dsin` without relying on `Math.sin`, you ask?!

Well... A little bit of research tells you that you can calculare `sin`, using the formula `sin(x) = x - x^3 / 3! + x^5 / 5! - x^7 / 7! + x^9 / 9! - ...`

In JavaScript, that would be something like this:

```
var sin = function(x) {
    var t1 = -1,t2 = 3,v1 = x,v2 = v1 + 1,it = 0;
    while (it < 10) {
        v2 = v1 + (t1 * pow(x, t2) / function(n){
        j = 1;
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
            j = j*i;
            return j;
        }(t2));
        t1 = -1 * t1;
        t2 += 2;
        v1 = v2;
        it++;
    }
    return v2;
}
```

You might notice that I put my factorial calculation in a lambda function. A more elegant solution would be to put your lambda function in a separate function, as you're likely to need it elsewhere.

Now, you just need to puzzle all the pieces together and wrap them in a nice object:

```
var Calc = (function(){
    return {
        E : 2.718281828459045,
        pow : function (base, exp) {
            var result = 1;
            while (exp--) {
                result *= base;
            }
            return result;
        },
        fact : function(n){
            j = 1;
            for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
                j = j*i;
            return j;
        },
        sin : function(x) {
            var t1 = -1,t2 = 3,v1 = x,v2 = v1 + 1,it = 0;
            while (it < 10) {
                v2 = v1 + (t1 * this.pow(x, t2) / this.fact(t2));
                t1 = -1 * t1;
                t2 += 2;
                v1 = v2;
                it++;
            }
            return v2;
        },
        dsin : function() {
            var piRatio = Math.PI / 180;
            return function dsin(degrees) {
                return Math.sin(degrees * piRatio);
            };
        }()
    };
})();
```

You can use the methods of these objects like this:

```
3+1*Calc.dsin(20)*Calc.pow(Calc.E,3)
```

### Step 3: Parsing

If you actually want your application to read an expression like `3+1*sin(20)*e^3` directly, you should NOT use `eval()`. Instead, you should write your own parser.

The proper way to do this, is to first write a tokenizer that converts your expression to a syntax tree. Then, you pass your syntax tree to an interpreter that processes your syntax tree by running the calculation functions you've created in step 1.

For an in depth look into how to build a syntax tree and interpreter, you could take a look at [this tutorial](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2011/08/math-evaluator-in-javascript-part1.html).

Comment: See OP at _" do not want to use inbuilt math-functions."_ , http://stackoverflow.com/a/34707177/

Comment: @guest271314 : I only just noticed that, after the OP edited his question. I'm editing my answer as we speak.

Comment: Note also _"do not want to use inbuilt math-functions"_ was not included at original Question  http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34707076/1

Comment: I am a college student and it's a part of my assignment to perform my own functions in a calculator. And apologies for the troubles, its my first question at stackoverflow.

Comment: How one should parse the expression? Is converting it into postfix expression and then re-evaluating is the only option?

Comment: Well that was a pathetic response. I'm never asked for the solution of my assignment here. Secondly, I've designed the sin and the other functions myself, if you once again go through my question. I am stuck at a particular problem of HOW TO PARSE AN EXPRESSION, that what my question reflects.

Comment: @batman : "a pathetic response"? Is that really how you want to respond to people making an effort to help you? If you're not getting the answers you expect, then just maybe you're asking the wrong question. If you want to know how to PARSE an expression and not how to actually make the calculations, you might at least want to mention the word "parse", "parser" or "parsing" in there... both in the TITLE and the body of your question! Anyway, in spite of your acting like a total douchebag, I added some info at the bottom on how to get started.

Comment: @johnslegers its my first time putting a question here, I expected some nice reply not "StackOverflow is frowned upon, as it is consider a form of cheating". I stuck at a problem and calling it a cheating, well show some kindness towards helping others. Yea I lacked the "parse" word, cz i was not able to figure out my mistake. anyways good luck.

Comment: @batman : Just giving you a friendly warning while still trying to actually answer your question (instead of downvoting and all kinds of nasty namecalling) is what's considered "kindness" here at StackOverflow. StackOverflow has some very strict (and often arbitrary) rules, with newcomers typically being punished harshly for not following them. Heck, I even wrote a (pretty popular) article about that (-> https://medium.com/@johnslegers/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d#.z1g44ooch). So if you think I'm the asshole here for warning you, you really don't know what you stepped into! ;-)

Comment: @batman : I just modified your question to better reflect what you're actually looking for

Comment: @JohnSlegers thanks a lot for your so much effort and solving my problem. I will try to implement this way. Thanks alot.

Comment: And please dont call it as "submitting school assignments on StackOverflow is frowned upon", I was just looking for my doubts answers not my Assignment aswers, Please I request you to correct it in your response above. :)

Comment: @batman : You said yourself that you're "a college student" and that "it's a part of [your] assignment to perform [your] own functions in a calculator". For any experienced programmer, it is obvious that you're working on an assignment, because you would NEVER write your own `Math.sin` equivalent in any real context. If you don't want people to make this obvious conclusion, just leave out the "I do not want to use built-in math-functions" part and focus on what you're actually looking for : the parsing. Lying by saying "it's not an school assignment, its just a doubt" only makes it worse, IMO!

Comment: @JohnSlegers I think I did a mistake of asking my doubt here, Your response is constantly shouting that you got a problem with me. Thanks.

Comment: @batman : I don't have a problem with you. I'm trying to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a parser that does what you need. It's called [SwanJS](https://github.com/onlabsorg/swan-js/blob/main/README.md) and it doesn't use `eval` or `new Function`.

Installation:

```
npm install @onlabsorg/swan-js
```

Usage:

```js
const swan = require('@onlabsorg/swan-js');  // It works also in the browser
const evaluate = swan.parse("3 + 1 * sin(20) * e**3");
const context = swan.createContext({
   sin: Math.sin,  // or your own sin function
   e: Math.E
});
const value = await evaluate(context);
```

If you don't like `**` as power operator, you may change it, but that's not well documented. Look at `/lib/interpreter.js` to see how to define a new grammar or ask me if you prefer.

Answer (score -3):

If you want more mathematical functionalities in addition to the [**standard JavaScript math library**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math), then you may want to use a third party library like [**math.js**](http://mathjs.org/).

To use this library, first include it in your HTML :

```
 <script src='path/to/math.js'></script>
```

Then, you can just use the `math.eval` method to evaluate your expression :

```
math.eval('3+1*sin(20)*e^3');
```

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: I want to know HOW TO SOLVE THE EXPRESSION.

Comment: "Use a library. Here is a link to a library. Here is a link to some documentation" is still "barely more than a link to an external site"