# How to find union and intersection with multiple sets in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, set

I'm trying to find a good approach to solve quite simple problem. 
For example, let us say that there are three sets (there might be more):

```
Set<Integer> A = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
Set<Integer> B = [2,4,6,8,10]
Set<Integer> C = [1,3,6,9]
```

Now, how to find answer to this equation: 
`(A or B) and (B or C)`. 
Basically *and* and *or* are intersection and union. 
So the answer to this would be just a single set. 
The answer to above operation would be:

```
[1,2,3,4,6,8,10]
```

I have done methods that find union and intersection with two sets, but I'm stuck in the point where there might be more than one operation in the equation.
And the operation length depends on the user input. It might be different each time

```
// intersection
private Set<Integer> intersection(Set setA, Set setB){
            return (Set<Integer>) setA.stream()
                 .filter(setB::contains)
                 .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        }
// union
   private Set<Integer> union(Set setA, Set setB){
    Set<Integer> result = new HashSet<Integer>(setA);
    result.addAll(setB);
    return result;
}
```

All approaches in Stackoverflow are based on two sets...

Comment: How about `Set.retainAll()`?

Comment: What about it? My intersection method is faster than retainAll().

Comment: `intersaction(union(A,B),union(B,C));` shall do the job ?

Comment: It does, but if you read the question carefully, it says that the equation might be dynamic. So one time it might be  `(A or B) and C`, the other time `A or C and B`...It depends on what user asks or types

Comment: *My intersection method is faster than retainAll*, I'd be careful with such statements, I'd say it is at most as fast as Set's `retainAll()`.

Comment: But honestly the question isn't very clear - is this about **parsing user's input**? I.e. if user enters `(A or B) and C` then program acts accordingly, e.g. `intersection(union(A, B), C)`, etc

Comment: Yes, basically, that is what I am looking for.

Comment: Then you may wanna look at this question for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114586/smart-design-of-a-math-parser, but instead of the usual math operators you'll use your Set operators/operations.

Comment: I will take a look. Cheers!