# How do you interpret a users input and turn it into a math function?

Tags: python, math, graphing

I am creating a graphing calculator and I need to figure out how to get the function the user wants. You know how on Desmos, they take the function the user enters and graphs it? I do not know how to take the input of lets say for example: ((x^3)+1)/6x and understand what the user just entered.

It would look something like this:
`function = input('f(x) = ')`

I need it to handle users putting in stuff like sqrt() and other things for graphing as well. Thanks

Comment: Why not parse it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Smart design of a math parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114586/smart-design-of-a-math-parser)

Answer (score 0):

[Copying this post's answers:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114586/smart-design-of-a-math-parser)

> A pretty good approach would involve two steps. The first step involves [converting the expression from infix to postfix](http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/infix_postfix/algorithms/infix-postfix/index.htm) (e.g. via [Dijkstra's shunting yard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)) notation. Once that's done, it's pretty trivial to write a [postfix evaluator](http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/infix_postfix/algorithms/postfix-evaluation/index.htm).

Comment: links are dead.

Comment: thanks for the help but yeah, the links are dead :(