# Get the last item in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, es2022

Here is my JavaScript code so far:

```
var linkElement = document.getElementById("BackButton");
var loc_array = document.location.href.split('/');
var newT = document.createTextNode(unescape(capWords(loc_array[loc_array.length-2]))); 
linkElement.appendChild(newT);
```

Currently it takes the second to last item in the array from the URL. However, I want to do a check for the last item in the array to be `"index.html"` and if so, grab the third to last item instead.

Answer (score 2439, accepted):

```
if (loc_array[loc_array.length - 1] === 'index.html') {
   // do something
} else {
   // something else
}
```

In the event that your server serves the same file for "index.html" and "inDEX.htML" you can also use: `.toLowerCase()`.

Though, you might want to consider doing this server-side if possible: it will be cleaner and work for people without JS.

---

**EDIT - ES-2022**

Using ES-2022 [`Array.at()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at), the above may be written like this:

```
if (loc_array.at(-1) === 'index.html') {
   // do something
} else {
   // something else
}
```

Comment: if you just need last item you can you Array.pop()

Comment: @BadriDerakhshan That would inevitably remove the last element from the array before returning it so this is not an option if you merely want to inspect the last element of the array. You would also have to push it back to restore the array to its former state.

Comment: You have to check whether array is empty. Empty array is legal array.

Comment: The solution from @BadriDerakhshan is useful for cases where the array created is temporary. For eg. instead of `x = string.split('/'); return x[x.length-1]`, you could do `return x.split('/').pop()`

Comment: Doesn't work on *Safari*

Comment: at() method is not supported by Safari IOS, Chrome IOS, and Samsung Internet
https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_string_at

Comment: (node:19430) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: allMessages.at is not a function

Comment: I rolled back the update suggesting to use `.at` as it was added by an entirely different user and is an entirely different approach than the one written by the original author.  Here's a dedicated answer with the `.at` approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61847169/1108305

Comment: DO NOT use `Array.pop()` because it is doing something else, just use `.at(-1)`

Comment: OMG - SIR thank you. I've been working on this for days. POP IS A HORRIBLE THING. pop() and typescript DONT mix. lol don't do it. do this. omg thank you sir.

Comment: Unfortunately, `at()` has a possible `undefined` in typescript

Answer (score 1624):

Not sure if there's a drawback, but this seems quite concise:

```
arr.slice(-1)[0]
```

or

```
arr.slice(-1).pop()
```

Both will return `undefined` if the array is empty.

Comment: using destructuring is nice too: `const [lastItem] = arr.slice(-1)`

Comment: @Badrush slice() makes new array with a copy of a single element, and pop modifies only that copy. the original array remains unharmed

Comment: But you should avoid creating new arrays unless this code is not called often. Otherwise it will put an extra strain on garbage collection, and/or will make browser use more memory.

Comment: @mvmn i did a benchmark a long time ago, throughput was around one or two million calls per second on a single 2.4ghz thread. so unless you have solve problems you shouldn't solve in JS anyways, it won't be noticable (iirc slowdown compared to arr[arr.length-1] was 50-100x)

Comment: this method is very slow

Comment: @Govan please see my comment. you can call this an exorbitant number of times per second. if you need more, or have the array length readily available, use normal array access for maximum performance `arr[arr.length-1]`

Answer (score 423):

Use [Array.pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop):

```
var lastItem = anArray.pop();
```

**Important** : This returns the last element *and* ***removes*** it from the array

Comment: especially great for something like: `filename.split('.').pop()`

Comment: it doesnt only return the last element but removes it !

Comment: `const lastItem = [...anArray].pop()` would be a way to avoid the mutation

Answer (score 219):

A shorter version of what @chaiguy posted:

```
Array.prototype.last = function() {
    return this[this.length - 1];
}
```

Reading the -1 index returns `undefined` already.

**EDIT:**

These days the preference seems to be using modules and to avoid touching the prototype or using a global namespace.

```
export function last(array) {
    return array[array.length - 1];
}
```

Comment: If it's not obvious how this is to be actually used, here's an example: `var lastItem = [3,2,1,5].last();`. The value of `lastItem` is `5`.

Comment: This answer is correct and also pretty clean BUT(!!!) A rule of thumb using Javascript is that `Do NOT modify objects you Do NOT own`. It's dangerous because of many reasons, such as 1. Other developers working in your team could get confused as this method is not standard 2.with any update in libraries or even using a lower or higher ECMAScript version it could easily get LOST!

Comment: For anyone wondering, this breaks Array.forEach().  I still agree that modifying prototypes is not the worst thing out there, but this one is bad.

Comment: Imo there's not such a big problem with modifying `Array.prototype`, but you should use `Object.assign(Array.prototype, 'last', { value: function () { … } });`. Otherwise the property will be enumerable.

Comment: @FarzadYousefzadeh [Interesting article](https://javascript.info/native-prototypes) that tells when and how to modify a JS native prototype.

Comment: @Breakingnotsobad Sure polyfilling is approved but keep in mind that it's only done for standard methods or soon to be standard for that matter. `last` is no standard in this case.

Comment: If you’re going to extend built-in prototypes or polyfill a property (i.e. monkey-patch), **please do it correctly**: for forward compatibility, check if the property exists _first_, then make the property non-enumerable so that the own keys of constructed objects aren’t polluted. For methods, use _actual_ [methods](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions). My recommendation: follow [these examples](/a/46491279/4642212) which demonstrate how to add a method that behaves like other built-in methods, as closely as possible.

Comment: note that the advice is to not modify original prototypes because if everybody did, there'd be conflicts all over the place. However, there really is only one thing that `Array.prototype.last()` can do: no matter the implementation, it'll return the last element, without removing it (because `.pop()` already exists for that), so in this case it's almost certainly perfectly fine, even if someone else _also_ implements that same function. They'll overwrite each other and keep doing exactly the same thing.

Comment: @黄雨伞 Actually, using `Object.assign()` does not seem to work here, whereas regular assignment to the prototype object does.

Answer (score 204):

Two options are:

```
var last = arr[arr.length - 1]
```

or

```
var last = arr.slice(-1)[0]
```

The former is faster, but the latter looks nicer

http://jsperf.com/slice-vs-length-1-arr

Comment: Thanks for for jsperf link. The second option is a nonsense from performance point of view.

Comment: The first option is also very obvious what it does. Second one not so much

Answer (score 150):

## Performance

Today 2020.05.16 I perform tests of chosen solutions on Chrome v81.0, Safari v13.1 and Firefox v76.0 on MacOs High Sierra v10.13.6

#### Conclusions

- `arr[arr.length-1]` (D) is recommended as fastest cross-browser solution
- mutable solution `arr.pop()` (A) and immutable `_.last(arr)` (L) are fast
- solutions I, J are slow for long strings
- solutions H, K (jQuery) are slowest on all browsers

[image]

#### Details

I test two cases for solutions:

- mutable: [A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11034866/860099),
  [B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9730383/860099),
  [C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26580838/860099),
- immutable: [D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3216041/860099),
  [E](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12099341/860099),
  [F](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46485581/860099),
  [G](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12099341/860099),
  [H](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44596873/860099),
  [I](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52349873/860099),
  J (my),
- immutable from external libraries: [K](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16667790/860099),
  [L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20978270/860099),
  [M](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53425011/860099),

for two cases

- short string - 10 characters - you can run test [HERE](https://jsbench.me/81ka8jmb83/1)
- long string - 1M characters - you can run test [HERE](https://jsbench.me/jlka8l6uz6/1)

```js
function A(arr) {
  return arr.pop();
}

function B(arr) {  
  return arr.splice(-1,1);
}

function C(arr) {  
  return arr.reverse()[0]
}

function D(arr) {
  return arr[arr.length - 1];
}

function E(arr) {
  return arr.slice(-1)[0] ;
}

function F(arr) {
  let [last] = arr.slice(-1);
  return last;
}

function G(arr) {
  return arr.slice(-1).pop();
}

function H(arr) {
  return [...arr].pop();
}

function I(arr) {  
  return arr.reduceRight(a => a);
}

function J(arr) {  
  return arr.find((e,i,a)=> a.length==i+1);
}

function K(arr) {  
  return $(arr).get(-1);
}

function L(arr) {  
  return _.last(arr);
}

function M(arr) {  
  return _.nth(arr, -1);
}






// ----------
// TEST
// ----------

let loc_array=["domain","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","file"];

log = (f)=> console.log(`${f.name}: ${f([...loc_array])}`);

[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M].forEach(f=> log(f));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha256-VeNaFBVDhoX3H+gJ37DpT/nTuZTdjYro9yBruHjVmoQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Example results for Chrome for short string

[image]

Comment: What is the numbers mentioned? Is higher better?

Comment: I could guess the results even without you having to run them, lol. But I don't think that performance matters much in this case.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, which didn't discuss performance. There are many other considerations other than performance for choosing a particular solution.

Answer (score 101):

Getting the last item in an array is possible via the `length` property. Since the array count starts at 0, you can pick the last item by referencing the `array.length - 1` item

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4];
const last = arr[arr.length - 1];
console.log(last); // 4
```

Another option is using the new `Array.prototype.at()` method which takes an integer value and returns the item at that index. Negative integers count back from the last item in the array so if we want the last item we can just pass in `-1`

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4];
const last = arr.at(-1);
console.log(last); // 4
```

Another option is using the new `findLast` method. You can see the proposal [here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-array-find-from-last) (currently in stage 4)

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4];
const last = arr.findLast(x => true);
console.log(last); // 4
```

Another option is using the `Array.prototype.slice()` method which returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object.

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4];
const last = arr.slice(-1)[0];
console.log(last); // 4
```

Comment: imo it should be `arr.findLast(() => true);` since your version would not "find" falsy values like `0` or `""`, ...

Answer (score 83):

Here's how to get it with no effect on the original ARRAY

```
a = [1,2,5,6,1,874,98,"abc"];
a.length; //returns 8 elements
```

If you use pop(), it will **modify your array**

```
a.pop();  // will return "abc" AND REMOVES IT from the array 
a.length; // returns 7
```

But you can use this so it has **no effect** on the original array:

```
a.slice(-1).pop(); // will return "abc" won't do modify the array 
                   // because slice creates a new array object 
a.length;          // returns 8; no modification and you've got you last element
```

Comment: you should do slice(-1).pop(), otherwise you copy the entire array (you really only need to copy the last element).

Comment: No need for that `pop()` then: just do `arr.slice(-1)[0]`

Answer (score 60):

The "cleanest" ES6 way (IMO) would be:

```
const foo = [1,2,3,4];
const bar = [...foo].pop();
```

This avoids mutating `foo`, as `.pop()` would had, if we didn't used the spread operator.
That said, I like aswell the `foo.slice(-1)[0]` solution.

Comment: You can also use the array destructuring to make it *more* ES6 ;) https://stackoverflow.com/a/46485581/31671

Comment: Note that this solution performs a copy of the entire array.

Comment: It's just as unreadable as `.slice(-1)[0]` but it's slower. Might as well use `.slice`

Comment: Copying the whole array just for "clean" syntax seems silly to me. It doesnt even look that nice

Answer (score 57):

## `const [lastItem] = array.slice(-1);`

[Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) with -1 can be used to create a new Array containing only the last item of the original Array, you can then use [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to create a variable using the first item of that new Array.

```js
const lotteryNumbers = [12, 16, 4, 33, 41, 22];
const [lastNumber] = lotteryNumbers.slice(-1);

console.log(lotteryNumbers.slice(-1));
// => [22]
console.log(lastNumber);
// => 22
```

Comment: The `.slice(-1)` answer was already given multiple times, starting [in 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12099341/1269037), and its implications were discussion in detail (unlike here). Please do not give repetitive answers just to get some upvotes.

Comment: I like this answer the best of all. The other .slice(-1) answers I have seen use [0] rather than destructuring. A comment by @diachedelic suggested this kind of destructuring, but it deserves to be an answer rather than a comment, in my opinion. Nice examples and links also.

Comment: Yeah those other answers aren't the same Dan, you're missing the use of destructuring assignment from the Array produced by slice(-1).

Comment: This also allows you to pick e.g. the last two items in a nice syntax: `const [secondLast, last] = lotteryNumbers.slice(-2)`

Answer (score 57):

> Previously you can use `x[x.length - 1]`
> Update: Since the most recent updates we can use the below method.

```js
const y = x.at(-1)
```

Comment: Definitely better to just use `arr[arr.length - 1]` as it is both more readable and nearly an order of magnitude faster on most browsers.

Comment: @acnebs I agree, why make it harder when you can make it easier.

Answer (score 47):

You can use relative indexing with [`Array#at`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at):

```js
const myArray = [1, 2, 3]

console.log(myArray.at(-1))
// => 3
```

Comment: And as of 3/2021 it's still in proposal and not supported by any browser

Comment: This is supported [since Firefox 88 (Nightly only) and Safari 14.1 (with `jscOptions=--useAtMethod=true`)](//web.archive.org/web/20210606095430/https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/#test-.at()_method_on_the_built-in_indexables). The `lastItem` proposal will probably be withdrawn.

Comment: now on chrome92 it is supported. https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6123640410079232

Comment: Good answer, though it would be better if it were called out that this is a new method that's not fully supported by all modern browsers, and not supported by older browsers.

Comment: @M.Justin There’s a link to documentation which has a browser support table — should be enough. I’d prefer the most modern solutions to be highlighted. Most things can be polyfilled or transpiled to older environments automatically. In a rapidly evolving ecosystem, developers should probably reconsider writing code for older environments _by hand_ or assuming that everything is supported everywhere.

Comment: Has good browser support now: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 46):

I'd rather use `array.pop()` than indexes.

```
while(loc_array.pop()!= "index.html"){
}
var newT = document.createTextNode(unescape(capWords(loc_array[loc_array.length])));
```

this way you always get the element previous to index.html (providing your array has isolated index.html as one item). **Note:** You'll lose the last elements from the array, though.

Answer (score 39):

```
const lastElement = myArray[myArray.length - 1];
```

This is the best options from performance point of view (~1000 times faster than `arr.slice(-1)`).

Comment: How does this add anything to the top answer?

Answer (score 34):

You can use this pattern...

```
let [last] = arr.slice(-1);
```

While it reads rather nicely, keep in mind it creates a new array so it's less efficient than other solutions but it'll almost never be *the* performance bottleneck of your application.

Answer (score 31):

If one wants to get the last element in one go, he/she may use [`Array#splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
lastElement = document.location.href.split('/').splice(-1,1);
```

Here, there is no need to store the split elements in an array, and then get to the last element. If getting last element is the only objective, this should be used.

Note: **This changes the original array** by removing its last element. Think of `splice(-1,1)` as a `pop()` function that pops the last element.

Comment: Doesn't this return the last element in an array, instead of the last element itself?

Comment: @tozazaburo isn't that the same thing?

Comment: this modifies the array. you could use slice(-1) instead of splice(-1) to leave the original array untouched. 
@AramKocharyan no its not, compare ```["hi"]``` vs ```"hi"```.

Answer (score 31):

Getting the last item of an array can be achieved by using the **slice** method with negative values.

You can read more about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) at the bottom.

```
var fileName = loc_array.slice(-1)[0];
if(fileName.toLowerCase() == "index.html")
{
  //your code...
}
```

Using pop() will change your array, which is not always a good idea.

Comment: Slice returns an array, though, so use `arr.slice(-1)[0]`, like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216013/get-the-last-item-in-an-array/12099341#12099341).

Comment: If performance is an issue, know that this method is a lot slower than `array[array.length - 1]` http://jsperf.com/get-last-item-from-array/13

Answer (score 31):

**Multiple ways to find last value of an array in javascript**

- **Without affecting original array**

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

console.log(arr.slice(-1)[0])
console.log(arr[arr.length-1])
const [last] = [...arr].reverse();
console.log(last)

let copyArr = [...arr];
console.log(copyArr.reverse()[0]);
```

- **Modifies original array**

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

console.log(arr.pop())
arr.push(5)
console.log(...arr.splice(-1));
```

- **By creating own helper method**

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

Object.defineProperty(arr, 'last', 
{ get: function(){
  return this[this.length-1];
 }
})

console.log(arr.last);
```

Comment: If your first example where you state *"Without affecting original array"* and by doing as suggested: `console.log(arr.reverse()[0])`  - congratulations, you just modified the original array.

Answer (score 29):

This question has been around a long time, so I'm surprised that no one mentioned just putting the last element back on after a `pop()`.

`arr.pop()` is exactly as efficient as `arr[arr.length-1]`, and both are the same speed as `arr.push()`.

Therefore, you can get away with:

---EDITED [check that `thePop` isn't `undefined` before pushing]---

```
let thePop = arr.pop()
thePop && arr.push(thePop)
```

---END EDIT---

Which can be reduced to this (same speed [EDIT: but unsafe!]):

```
arr.push(thePop = arr.pop())    //Unsafe if arr empty
```

This is twice as slow as `arr[arr.length-1]`, but you don't have to stuff around with an index. That's worth gold on any day.

Of the solutions I've tried, and in multiples of the Execution Time Unit (ETU) of `arr[arr.length-1]`:

### [Method]..............[ETUs 5 elems]...[ETU 1 million elems]

```
arr[arr.length - 1]      ------> 1              -----> 1

let myPop = arr.pop()
arr.push(myPop)          ------> 2              -----> 2

arr.slice(-1).pop()      ------> 36             -----> 924  

arr.slice(-1)[0]         ------> 36             -----> 924  

[...arr].pop()           ------> 120            -----> ~21,000,000 :)
```

The last three options, ESPECIALLY `[...arr].pop()`, get VERY much worse as the size of the array increases. On a machine without the memory limitations of my machine, `[...arr].pop()` probably maintains something like it's 120:1 ratio. Still, no one likes a resource hog.

Comment: If initial array can be empty, this approach will result incorrectly and `[]` will be turned into `[undefined]`. You need to protect backward push with explicit `undefined` check, something like `myPop !== undefined && arr.push(myPop)`

Answer (score 24):

Just putting another option here.

```
loc_array.splice(-1)[0] === 'index.html'
```

I found the above approach more clean and short onliner. Please, free feel to try this one.

***Note: It will modify the original array, if you don't want to modify it you can use `slice()`***

```
loc_array.slice(-1)[0] === 'index.html'
```

Thanks [@VinayPai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/468495/vinay-pai) for pointing this out.

Comment: According to the comment by https://stackoverflow.com/users/510036/qix-monica-was-mistreated on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050345/selecting-last-element-in-javascript-array and the tests at https://jsperf.com/last-array-element2  that is extremely slow

Comment: The `.slice(-1)` answer was already given multiple times, starting [in 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12099341/1269037), and its implications were discussion in detail (unlike here). Please do not give repetitive answers just to get some upvotes.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Thank you for your kind words. It was honest mistake, I didn't saw that answer before on same question and tried to help with what I know. Also if upvotes were my moto then you would have seen more duplicate answers on my profile.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Any way, way to encourage new members on the platform and a very great way to show their mistakes. Kudos to you man. Coming from such a strong profile, advocate, co-founder is very inspiring and I surely try not to follow such influencer and keep my ways polite enough to make new members comfortable.

Thanks for the lesson. It was good one ;)

Answer (score 22):

## Here's more Javascript art if you came here looking for it

In the spirit of another answer that used `reduceRight()`, but shorter:

```
[3, 2, 1, 5].reduceRight(a => a);
```

It relies on the fact that, in case you don't provide an initial value, the very last element is selected as the initial one (check the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight)). Since the callback just keeps returning the initial value, the last element will be the one being returned in the end.

Beware that this should be considered *Javascript art* and is by no means the way I would recommend doing it, mostly because it runs in O(n) time, but also because it hurts readability.

### And now for the serious answer

The best way I see (considering you want it more concise than `array[array.length - 1]`) is this:

```
const last = a => a[a.length - 1];
```

Then just use the function:

```
last([3, 2, 1, 5])
```

The function is actually useful in case you're dealing with an anonymous array like `[3, 2, 1, 5]` used above, otherwise you'd have to instantiate it twice, which would be inefficient and ugly:

```
[3, 2, 1, 5][[3, 2, 1, 5].length - 1]
```

Ugh.

For instance, here's a situation where you have an anonymous array and you'd have to define a variable, but you can use `last()` instead:

```
last("1.2.3".split("."));
```

Answer (score 22):

ES6 object destructuring is another way to go.

```js
const {length, [length-1]: last}=[1,2,3,4,5]
console.log(last)
```

You extract **length** property from Array using object destructuring. You create another dynamic key using already extracted key by **[length-1]** and assign it to **last**, all in one line.

Comment: Thanks, Can you explain what exactly it does ?

Comment: from my understanding (I could be wrong) `length` is the first index of the array. but `[length-1]` is the last index (the one before it). `:last` is the alias used to define the last index (or the one before the first one to be exact)

Comment: @TarunNagpal arrays are like objects, they have a length property and indices as properties. here we destructor `length` then use [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) `[length -1]` to get the last element.

Answer (score 21):

For those not afraid to overload the Array prototype (and with [enumeration masking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Enumerable_attribute) you shouldn't be):

```
Object.defineProperty( Array.prototype, "getLast", {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function() {
        return this[ this.length - 1 ];
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 20):

I generally use [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/), with it you can just do

```
if (_.last(loc_array) === 'index.html'){
  etc...
}
```

For me that is more semantic than `loc_array.slice(-1)[0]`

Answer (score 19):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) solves this neatly:

```
> $([1,2,3]).get(-1)
3
> $([]).get(-1)
undefined
```

Answer (score 19):

#### ECMA 2022

With ECMA 2022 you have a new property `at()`. To get the last element from a Array or a string you can use `at` with the negative index `-1`. `[1,2,3].at(-1)`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at

If you like more fluent like arr.last to receive the last item you can define your own property to the array object.

```js
if (!Array.prototype.hasOwnProperty("last")) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "last", {
    get() {
      return this.at(-1);
    }
  });
}

a = [1,2,3];
console.log(a.last);
```

Answer (score 15):

To prevent removing last item from origin array you could use

```js
Array.from(myArray).pop()
```

Mostly supported of all browsers (ES6)

Answer (score 14):

[In ECMAScript proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposals) [Stage 1](https://github.com/tc39/proposals#stage-1) there is a suggestion to add an array property that will return the last element: [proposal-array-last](https://github.com/keithamus/proposal-array-last).

Syntax:

```
arr.lastItem // get last item
arr.lastItem = 'value' // set last item

arr.lastIndex // get last index
```

You can use [polyfill](https://github.com/keithamus/proposal-array-last#polyfill).

Proposal author: [Keith Cirkel](https://github.com/keithamus)([chai](https://github.com/chaijs/chai) autor)

Answer (score 13):

## Whatever you do don't *just* use `reverse()` !!!

A few answers mention `reverse` but don't mention the fact that `reverse` modifies the original array, and doesn't (as in some other language or frameworks) return a copy.

```
var animals = ['dog', 'cat'];

animals.reverse()[0]
"cat"

animals.reverse()[0]
"dog"

animals.reverse()[1]
"dog"

animals.reverse()[1]
"cat"
```

This can be the worst type of code to debug!

Comment: If you do want a reversed **copy** of your array, you can use the spread operator now. e.g. `[...animals].reverse()`

Comment: you can simply copy the array before using reverse `[1,3,4,5,"last"].slice().reverse()[0]`

Answer (score 13):

I think this should work fine.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var last_element = arr.reverse()[0];
```

Just reverse the array and get the first element.

Edit: As mentioned below, the original array will be reversed. To avoid that you can change the code to:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var last_element = arr.slice().reverse()[0];
```

This will create a copy of the original array.

Comment: This will alter the original array

Comment: The slice() copies the array

var arr = [1, 2, 3];
last_element = arr.slice().reverse()[0];

Comment: @Zellius Might as well just pop the last element if you're going to slice the array. i.e. `arr.slice().pop()`

Answer (score 12):

Personally I would upvote answer by kuporific / kritzikratzi. The array[array.length-1] method gets very ugly if you're working with nested arrays.

```
var array = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
​
array.slice(-1)[0]
​
//instead of 
​
array[array.length-1]
​
//Much easier to read with nested arrays
​
array.slice(-1)[0].slice(-1)[0]
​
//instead of
​
array[array.length-1][array[array.length-1].length-1]
```

Answer (score 10):

You can add a `last()` function to the `Array` prototype.

```
Array.prototype.last = function () {
    return this[this.length - 1];
};
```

**EDIT:**

You can use a `Symbol` to avoid incompatibility with other code:

```js
const last = Symbol('last');
Array.prototype[last] = function() {
    return this[this.length - 1];
};

console.log([0, 1][last]());
```

Comment: If you’re going to extend built-in prototypes or polyfill a property (i.e. monkey-patch), **please do it correctly**: for forward compatibility, check if the property exists _first_, then make the property non-enumerable so that the own keys of constructed objects aren’t polluted. For methods, use _actual_ [methods](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions). My recommendation: follow [these examples](/a/46491279/4642212) which demonstrate how to add a method that behaves like other built-in methods, as closely as possible.

Answer (score 10):

As per ES2022, You can use [Array.at()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) method which takes an integer value and returns the item at that index. Allowing for positive and negative integers. Negative integers count back from the last item in the array.

**Demo :**

```js
const href = 'www.abc.com/main/index.html';
const loc_array = href.split('/');

// To access elements from an array we can use Array.at()
console.log(loc_array.at(-1)); // This will return item at last index.
```

Answer (score 9):

You could add a new [property getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters) to the [prototype of `Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) so that it is accessible through all instances of `Array`.

Getters allow you to access the return value of a function just as if it were the value of a property. The return value of the function of course is the last value of the array (`this[this.length - 1]`).

Finally you wrap it in a condition that checks whether the `last`-property is still `undefined` (not defined by another script that might rely on it).

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'last', {
    get : function() {
        return this[this.length - 1];
    }
});

// Now you can access it like
[1, 2, 3].last;            // => 3
// or
var test = [50, 1000];
alert(test.last);          // Says '1000'
```

[Does not work in IE ≤ 8.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: `Array.prototype.last` is always `undefined`? The if isn't working under Chrome 36

Answer (score 8):

**EDITED:**

Recently I came up with one more solution which I now think is the best for my needs:

```
function w(anArray) {
  return {
    last() {
      return anArray [anArray.length - 1];
    };
  };
}
```

With the above definition in effect I can now say:

```
let last = w ([1,2,3]).last();
console.log(last) ; // -> 3
```

The name **"w"** stands for "wrapper". 
You can see how you could easily add more 
methods besides 'last()' to this wrapper.

I say "best for my needs", because this allows
me to easily add other such "helper methods"
to any JavaScript built-in type. What comes 
to mind are the car() and cdr() of Lisp for 
instance.

Comment: Why use a wrapper? If you have to call a `w` function just make the function return the last item.

Comment: `w([1,2,3]).length` is undefined. `w([1,2,3])[1]` is undefined. Does not seem like a wrapper to me. And there is a syntax error. You have an extra ';'. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49725374/458321 for how to write a class wrapper (SutString class) and use reflection to populate that wrapper. Though, imho, wrappers are overkill. Better to use encapsulation, like you almost have. `return { arr: anArray, last() { return anArray[anArray.length - 1]; } };`. Also, w is way too generic. Call is ArrayW or something.

Answer (score 7):

I think the easiest to understand for beginners and super inefficient way is:

```
var array = ['fenerbahce','arsenal','milan'];
var reversed_array = array.reverse(); //inverts array [milan,arsenal,fenerbahce]
console.log(reversed_array[0]) // result is "milan".
```

Comment: This solution takes O(n) more memory and takes O(n) time. It's really not the ideal solution.

Comment: it must not start with fenerbahce. it must be like that: ['besiktas','galatasaray','trabzonspor','bursaspor','fenerbahce'] ;)

Answer (score 7):

## Functional programming with Ramda

If you're using JS, I would suggest checking out Ramda which is a functional-programming library (like Lodash and Underscore, except more advanced and modular). Ramda provides this with [R.last](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#last)

```
import * as R from 'ramda';
R.last(['fi', 'fo', 'fum']); //=> 'fum'
R.last([]); //=> undefined

R.last('abc'); //=> 'c'
R.last(''); //=> ''
```

It further provides `init`, `head`, `tail`. [List monster from (Learn You a Haskell)](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out)

[image: List Monster]

Comment: including library is not reasonable for getting last element,  if I do, I  would use https://underscorejs.org/#last

Comment: @Tebe Ramda is a newer more modern and modular version of Lodash which is the replacement for Underscore.js

Comment: yes, I tried ramda it tasted a bit not necessary overcomplicated at the first glance for me. Maybe I still don't think functional  enough and will get into it when my mind will be ready for it.  By the way, I  see you have experience with it,  how would look such code in ramda? _.chain([1,2,3]).map((val)=> {  return val*2 }).first().value()    -> result is 2. Does it support chaining ? I see ramda has method chain, but it looks like it's for smth else

Comment: @Tebe Like this `R.pipe(R.take(1), x=>x*2)` (also works with typescript)

Comment: would this code require more evil nesting if we add up more chaining?   E.g.__.chain([1,2,3]).map((val)=> { return val*2 })
 .filter((val)=> { return val > 3; })
 .map((val)=> { return val*2 })
 .first()
 .value()
  - https://paste.debian.net/1061022/ (please  see link with formatted code)  - result is 8

Comment: No, Pipe takes more than one function `const m = x => y => x * y; R.pipe(R.take(1), m(2), m(3), m(4))` What's the point here? I mean I'm down for helping you to learn Ramda but this has 0 to do with my answer? And it seems like you're a little bitter that you're struggling to grok Ramda so you downvoted me (not a good way to start a conversation). Keep on learning though. Btw, you can also do `x = R.pipe( R.take(1), y=>y*2 ); y = R.pipe( x, z => z*2 )`

Comment: whatever trevor, unfortunately there is no way to take this down back.  I'm going to upvote another your answer if it makes you feel better.  By the way I don't try to learn it now, I just tried to highlight the thing what ramda misses and which kept me in Underscore/Backbone. Defining another function in temp variable is messing around instead  of hiding things inside chaining.

Comment: You don't have to do that in fact, I would never do that for your case I would just pipe more than one thing. The point here is that ramda is doing function composition with pipe. And what Lodash is doing is wrapping an object in a base class that provides operators as methods. The Lodash method is a **very** bad idea. The reason why they do it is because legacy code that uses Lodash. For example, Rxjs, used to do things that way but now they use the pipe method too.

Comment: One of the great practical upsides of the pipe method is that any library can export functions that work with `pipe` and that you only need to import what you're using. In addition anything imported that you're not using is subject to "tree shaking" which Webpack can actually remove in a bundle (dead code goes away). This makes it the Ramba method more-pure (functionally), more concise (look at my example), faster (no wrapping of objects), and smaller (no need to import a class, or all of the operators, and you can remove operators you don't use automagically)

Comment: @Tebe if with can't take back" you mean a downvote, off course you can. If the user edits the answer, you can then retract the downvote.

Comment: Thank you one more time. So it looks functional programming has many sides, ramda just preaches one more way I didn't know before. Though not sure about badness of chaining. It's already into the core of ES6. E.g. [1,2,3].filter((val)=> { 
   return val > 1;
}).map((val) => { 
   return val*2;
}).push()  -> yields 2 .  I started this conversion at all because I remember myself wondering a few years ago when I wanted to switch to ramda and didn't find such  necessity in FP as chaining IMHO. Being modular and advanced is fine(if it's really so), though I would stake on convenience of usage.

Comment: @Tebe but the evilness of that method despite ES6's adoption is pretty apparent, for example to find the keys of an object you don't do `a.keys()`, you do `Object.keys(a)`? Why? Because likely somewhere someone extended `Object.prototype` to already have `keys` and es didn't want to break backwards compat. This isn't a problem though with the Ramda method. `R.pipe(R.keys, R.join(''))( {foo:1,bar:2} );` You just compose functions together.

Comment: Moreover, with ramda and lodash (and hopefully not es6) people create libraries to extend core functionality. Extending prototype is generally considered bad. That's why it's kind of funny that the lodash team thought it was a good idea to recreate that problem by making all objects that their operators take instances of the wrapper class. (which any extension of lodash would have to monkey patch to).

Comment: I don't understand why this answer got so many downvotes! Ramda is arguably better than both Lodash and Underscore. It is purely functional and clean even though it might be a bit hard to understand if someone is not used to functional programming. Its definitely a good answer to the problem though I still wouldn't recommend using a library if the only thing you have to do is to get the last element in an array.

Comment: Beyond the scope of the question. Lodash and Underscore, included. Ramda is full of abbreviations and jargon. Better suited to use an actual functional language + llvm / emscripten to produce web assembly. Which is still out of scope.

Answer (score 6):

I'll suggest to create helper function and reuse it every time, you'll need it. Lets make function more general to be able to get not only last item, but also second from the last and so on.

```
function last(arr, i) {
    var i = i || 0;
    return arr[arr.length - (1 + i)];
}
```

Usage is simple

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
last(arr);    //5
last(arr, 1); //4
last(arr, 9); //undefined
```

Now, lets solve the original issue

> Grab second to last item form array. If the last item in the loc_array is "index.html" grab the third to last item instead.

Next line does the job

```
last(loc_array, last(loc_array) === 'index.html' ? 2 : 1);
```

So, you'll need to rewrite

```
var newT = document.createTextNode(unescape(capWords(loc_array[loc_array.length-2])));
```

in this way

```
var newT = document.createTextNode(unescape(capWords(last(loc_array, last(loc_array) === 'index.html' ? 2 : 1))));
```

or use additional variable to increase readability

```
var nodeName = last(loc_array, last(loc_array) === 'index.html' ? 2 : 1);
var newT = document.createTextNode(unescape(capWords(nodeName)));
```

Answer (score 6):

Normally you are not supposed to mess with the prototype of built-in types but here is a hack/shortcut:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'last', {
  get() {
    return this[this.length - 1]; 
  }
});
```

This will allow all array objects to have a `last` property, which you can use like so:

```js
const letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
console.log(letters.last); // 'e'
```

You are not supposed to mess with a built-in type's prototype because you never when a new ES version will be released and in the event that a new version uses the same property name as your custom property, all sorts of breaks can happen. Also, it makes it hard for others to follow your code, especially for people joining the team. You COULD make the property to something that you know an ES version would never use, like `listLastItem` but that is at the discretion of the developer.

Or you can use a simple method:

```js
const getLast = (list) => list[list.length - 1];
const last = getLast([1,2,3]); // returns 3
```

Answer (score 6):

## Update - 27 October 2021 (Chrome 97+)

**[Proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-array-find-from-last) for `Array.prototype.findLast` is now on Stage 3!**

Here's how you can use it:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const last_element = array.findLast((item) => true);
console.log(last_element);
```

You can read more in [this V8 blog post](https://v8.dev/features/finding-in-arrays).

You can find more in ["New in Chrome" series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eXaog4gUIXI&ab_channel=GoogleChromeDevelopers).

Answer (score 5):

Using ES6/ES2015 spread operator (...) you can do the following way.

```js
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const [last] = [...data].reverse()
console.log(last)
```

Please notice that using spread operator and reverse we did not mutated original array, this is a pure way of getting a last element of the array.

Comment: Reversing an entire array just to get the last element is super inefficient.

Comment: @slang, agree. If you are doing hundreds to millions operations then you have to consider not to do it this way, but if you have to do it only several time than nobody will notice that. This example provides 'pure' call without changing actual data array.

Answer (score 5):

Using lodash [_.last(array)](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#last) Gets the last element of array.

```js
data = [1,2,3]
last = _.last(data)
console.log(last)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

How about something like below:

```
if ('index.html' === array[array.length - 1]) {  
   //do this 
} else { 
   //do that 
}
```

If using **Underscore** or **Lodash**, you can use `_.last()`, so something like:

```
if ('index.html' === _.last(array)) {  
   //do this 
} else { 
   //do that 
}
```

Or you can create your own last function:

```
const _last = arr => arr[arr.length - 1];
```

and use it like:

```
if ('index.html' === _last(array)) {  
   //do this 
} else { 
   //do that 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Will this work?

```
if (loc_array.pop() == "index.html"){
var newT = document.createTextNode(unescape(capWords(loc_array[loc_array.length-3])));
}
else{
var newT = document.createTextNode(unescape(capWords(loc_array[loc_array.length-2])));
}
```

Comment: No because `.pop()` returns the last element and also removes it, so your indexes change.

Comment: If you do not want your original array to be mutated then do `arr.slice().pop()` - this creates a new array

Comment: better when you don't care about array anymore!

Answer (score 4):

This method will not mess with your prototype.  It also guards against `0` length arrays, along with `null`/`undefined` arrays.  You can even override the default value if the returned default value might match an item in your array.

```js
const items = [1,2,3]
const noItems = []

/**
 * Returns the last item in an array.
 * If the array is null, undefined, or empty, the default value is returned.
 */
function arrayLast (arrayOrNull, defVal = undefined) {
  if (!arrayOrNull || arrayOrNull.length === 0) {
    return defVal
  }
  return arrayOrNull[arrayOrNull.length - 1]
}

console.log(arrayLast(items))
console.log(arrayLast(noItems))
console.log(arrayLast(null))

console.log(arrayLast(items, 'someDefault'))
console.log(arrayLast(noItems, 'someDefault'))
console.log(arrayLast(null, 'someDefault'))
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with lodash [`_.last`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#last) or [`_.nth`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#nth):

```js
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var last = _.nth(data, -1)
console.log(last)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this issue also without extracting an array from the url

This is my alternative

```
var hasIndex = (document.location.href.search('index.html') === -1) ? doSomething() : doSomethingElse();
```

!Greetings¡

Answer (score 3):

This is clean and efficient:

```
let list = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]

(xs => xs[xs.length - 1])(list)
```

If you install a pipe operator using Babel it becomes:

```
list |> (xs => xs[xs.length - 1])
```

Comment: I love that iife syntax so much. Thank you for making my life happily more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Another `ES6` only option would be to use `Array.find(item, index)=> {...})` as follows:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const last = arr.find((item, index) => index === arr.length - 1);
```

little practical value, posted to show that index is also available for your filtering logic.

Answer (score 3):

## Update 2020

```js
Array.prototype.last = function(){
    return this[this.length - 1];
}

let a = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5]];

console.log(a.last());
// [ 4, 5 ]
console.log(a.last().last());
// 5
```

---

### Setter and Getter

```js
Array.prototype.last = function(val=null) {
  if (this.length === 0) {
    if (val) this[0] = val;
    else return null; 
  }
  
  temp = this;
  while(typeof temp[temp.length-1] === "object") {
    temp = temp[temp.length-1];
  }
  
  if (val) temp[temp.length-1] = val; //Setter  
  else return temp[temp.length-1]; //Getter
  
}

var arr = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]];
console.log(arr.last()); // 'd'
    
arr.last("dd"); 
console.log(arr); // [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ [ 'a', 'b' ], [ 'c', 'dd' ] ] ]
```

Comment: Please avoid polluting prototypes.

Comment: @Sean, adding is a better practice compare to rewriting prototype.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to say but modifying prototypes you don't own makes your code prone to conflicts and hurts forward-compatibility. Prototype pollution is a known bad practice caught by JavaScript security bulletins.

Answer (score 2):

The [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) makes the fastest-performing method more concise, by not repeating the name of the array.

```
var lastItem = (a => a[a.length - 1])(loc_array);
```

Comment: But why write a method when you can access the last item directly... `var lastItem = a[a.length-1]`

Comment: This doesn't demonstrate creating a method, though. It shows off using an arrow function to "rename" loc_array to `a` within the context of the function. It's like doing `var getLast = a => a[a.length - 1]; var lastItem = getLast(loc_array)`, but the "getLast" function is in-lined, not separately defined.

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = ["stackoverflow", "starlink"];
var last = str[str.length-1];//basically you are putting the last index value into the array and storing it in la
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also a npm module, that add `last` to `Array.prototype`

```
npm install array-prototype-last --save
```

usage

```
require('array-prototype-last');

[1, 2, 3].last; //=> 3 

[].last; //=> undefined
```

Comment: source of function?

Comment: it's simalar to this? `Array.prototype.last = function(){ return this[this.length - 1]; }` + `Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'last', {enumerable: false});`

Comment: in your example last is function you should call it like ['a', 'b'].last() // 'b', while in module last is property and you can call it like ['a', 'b'].last // 'b'

Comment: ok it's a trik to remove `()` in code, but this "property" stay in fact a function called each time, right?

Answer (score 1):

For a readable and concise solution, you can use a combination of [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
const linkElement = document.getElementById("BackButton");
const loc_array = document.location.href.split('/');

// assign the last three items of the array to separate variables
const [thirdLast, secondLast, last] = loc_array.slice(-3);

// use the second last item as the slug...
let parentSlug = secondLast;

if (last === 'index.html') {
  // ...unless this is an index
  parentSlug = thirdLast;
}

const newT = document.createTextNode(
  unescape(
    capWords(parentSlug)
  )
);

linkElement.appendChild(newT);
```

But to simply get the last item in an array, I prefer this notation:

```js
const [lastItem] = loc_array.slice(-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### ES2023 Array Method [findLastIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findLastIndex)

> The `findLastIndex()` method iterates the array in reverse order and returns the index of the first element that satisfies the provided testing function. If no elements satisfy the testing function, -1 is returned.

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4];
const lastIndex = arr.findLastIndex(x => true);
console.log(arr[lastIndex]); // 4
```

PS: `findLastIndex()` method is supported by all browsers and on Node.js version 18+.
see [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findLastIndex#browser_compatibility)

Comment: This is the best option if you actually need to know the index number, but if you just want the last element then it's simpler to just use `arr.at(-1)` (added in ES2022). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75051635/560114

Answer (score 0):

Using [reduceRight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight):

```
[3,2,1,5].reduceRight((a,v) => a ? a : v);
```

Comment: This is actually a pretty creative way of doing it, although it does run in O(n) time because it still traverses the whole array.

Comment: If you don't mind, I made it even more concise by removing the unnecessary `return` and curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

simple answer

```
const array = [1,2,3]
array[array.length - 1]
```

Comment: Very good answer

Answer (score 0):

The pop() and slice() both method are faster. You can use pop() method if you are fine with modifying the array. If you don't want to change the array, the slice() method can be used.

```js
let arrItems = [12, 24, 60, 80, 10, 14, 123];
console.time('using array length');
let lastItem = arrItems[arrItems.length - 1];
console.log(lastItem);
console.timeEnd('using array length');

console.time('using slice method');
let lastItem1 = arrItems.slice(-1)[0];
console.log(lastItem1);
console.timeEnd('using slice method');

console.time('using pop method');
let lastItem2 = arrItems.pop();
console.log(lastItem2);
console.timeEnd('using pop method');

//Output:

//123
//using array length: 0.200ms
//123
//using slice method: 0.175ms
//123
//using pop method: 0.012ms
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your indices are random strings, уоu can use this:

```
arr[Object.keys(arr)[Object.keys(arr).length - 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use snippet that extends the functionality of arrays by adding a new method called last(). This method can be used various approach to retrieve the last item of an array. Choose one of the many possibilities:

```js
Array.prototype.last = function() {
  return this[this.length - 1]
  // return this.slice(-1)[0]
  // return this.at(-1)
  // return this.findLast(x => true)
  // return [...this].reverse()[0]
  // return this.reduceRight(_ => _)
  // return this.slice().reverse()[0]
  // return this.pop()
  // return this.splice(-1,1)[0]
  // return [...this].pop()
  // return this.find((_,i,a)=>a.length==i+1)
}


console.log([2,4,6].last()) // 6
console.log([1, 2, 3].last()) // 3
```

Answer (score -1):

The simple way to get last item of array:

```
var last_item = loc_array.reverse()[0];
```

Of course, we need to check to make sure array has at least one item first.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21481826)

Comment: The question is "How to get last item in an array", and my solution should works. :)

Comment: this is the slowest way to get the last element... what if the array has a million elements?

Comment: Terrible terrible idea! `reverse` changes the original array so if you run this twice in a row you get different results (asusming length > 1)

Answer (score -4):

to access the last element in array using c# we can use GetUpperBound(0)

(0) in case if this one dimention array

```
my_array[my_array.GetUpperBound(0)] //this is the last element in this one dim array
```

Comment: The question was how to do it in JavaScript :)

Answer (score -6):

```
array.reverse()[0]
```

That's so simple

Comment: Reverse modifies the original array. You should call Array.from(items).reverse()[0] for this method.

Comment: This produces such an unnecessary overhead. Even with the suggestion of @TamusJRoyce it's still bad, I wouldn't use it even for an array that is guaranteed to have no more than two items.