# javascript only get last number in chain

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a bunch of numbers coming back from an api. It looks like this

`1,2,3,4,5,6`

Now i'm only wanting the last digit to be displayed rather than all of them.

How would i go about doing this? I need to add `.slice` on the end but im not sure what to put in the `()`

Thanks
Sam

Comment: Is this `array` ? If yes then `arr[arr.length-1]`

Comment: [Selecting last element in JavaScript array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050345/selecting-last-element-in-javascript-array)

Comment: If it's an array, then `arr.pop()` returns the last member. If it's a string, then `string.split(',').pop()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
.slice(-1)[0]
```

or

```
.slice(-1).pop()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "1,2,3,4,5,6";    
var _lastNum = str.slice(-1*(str.length - str.lastIndexOf(",")-1)); // Will return 6;
```

Comment: "1,2,3,4,5,6".slice(-1)[0]

Comment: @Artem that is not required.

Answer (score 0):

By far, voids answer seems to be the most comfortable and shortest one. But if you attempt to use at least one of the numbers at any time again, you may use something like this:

```
var str = "1,2,3,4,5,6"
str = str.split(',')
var lastNum = str[str.length-1]
```

As RobG wrote, you could also do

```
var lastNum = str.pop()
```

Comment: Simpler as `str.split(',').pop()`. ;-)

Comment: In this case the array would lose its last element. Still edited my post to cover that too.