# Fetching last element for map within map within map in rxjs 6.3

Tags: javascript, angular, multidimensional-array, rxjs, angular-directive

I have written the following code to return an object `transformedRes` having 4 values:
`Id, name, message, status`
In case of `status`, I am getting an `audits` array with almost `100 elements`. However, I need to fetch only the last element from `audit` and then the `audit.msg` from the last `audit` element

```
const transformedRes = {
  Id: res.data.map(host => host._id),
  name: res.data.map(host => host._val.hostName),
  message: res.data.map(host => host._val.message),
  status: res.data.map(host => {
    if (host) {
      const auditsMsg = host._val.audits.map(audit =>  audit.msg);
    }
  })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use map, if you just want the last element?

```
const transformedRes = {
  Id: res.data.map(host => host._id),
  name: res.data.map(host => host._val.hostName),
  message: res.data.map(host => host._val.message),
  status: res.data.map(host => {
    return host._val.audits[host._val.audits.length-1].msg; //Last element of audits array
  }
};
```

More about fetching the last element of an array is described in this stack post: [Selecting last element in JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050345/selecting-last-element-in-javascript-array)