# How the get the last element in an array items using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have a list of array items like this:

```js
const items = [
  { a: 1 },
  { b: 2 },
  { c: 3 },
]
```

How can I return / log the last element: `{ c: 3 }`

Here's what I've tried so far:

```js
let newarray = items.map((item) => {
    console.log(item);
})

console.log(newarray);
```

Comment: if you *really wanted* to use es6 `[last, ...others] = items.reverse(); console.log(last)` (don't do this)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Destructuring to get the last element of an array in es6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33064377/destructuring-to-get-the-last-element-of-an-array-in-es6)

Answer (score 28):

#### Update 2021

You can use the [`Array.at()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) method, which was moved to [Stage 4  in Aug, 2021](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/main/finished-proposals.md)

```js
['a','b','c'].at(-1) // 'c'
```

#### Further Reading

- **Docs**

  - [MDN - Array.prototype.at()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at)
  - [Proposal - Relative Indexing Method](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-relative-indexing-method)
  - [tc39 spec - Array.at](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.at)
  - [CanIUse - JavaScript built-in: Array: at](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_array_at)
- **Stack Overflow**

  - [Get the last item in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3216013/1366033)
  - [Selecting last element in JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9050345/1366033)
  - [Destructuring to get the last element of an array in es6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33064377/1366033)

Comment: Good answer. But misleading in terms, that it states that `Array.at()` is part of a living ECMAScript 2021 standard - whereas as of writing this comment (04.02.22) it's still a Stage 4 proposal.  https://tc39.es/proposal-relative-indexing-method/#sec-array-prototype-additions

Comment: Thanks @avalanche1 - updated the answer to clarify.  Seems like stage 4 is a finished proposal and will be released whenever the next version of ECMAScript ships.

Answer (score 10):

just log the length minus 1, nothing to do with es6:

```
console.log(items[items.length - 1])
```

Answer (score 3):

If your list has 3 items, the length is 3 but the last item index is 2, since arrays start at 0, so simply do this:

```
console.log(items[items.length - 1]);
```

Doc: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 2):

I want to let you try something different:

```
console.log(items.slice(-1));
```

Comment: items.slice(-1)[0]

Comment: In case the previous comment isn't clear, `slice()` returns an array. `items.slice(-1)` returns an array containing the last element of `items`.  `items.slice(-1)[0]` is the element itself, i.e. the last item in `items`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not required to use ES6 to perform the operation you're asking about. You could use either of the following:

```
/**
 * The last value in the array, `3`, is at the '2' index in the array.
 * To retrieve this value, get the length of the array, '3', and 
 * subtract 1. 
 */
const items = [1, 2, 3];
const lastItemInArray = items[items.length - 1] // => 3
```

or:

```
/**
 * Make a copy of the array by calling `slice` (to ensure we don't mutate
 * the original array) and call `pop` on the new array to return the last  
 * value from the new array.
 */
const items = [1, 2, 3];
const lastItemInArray = items.slice().pop(); // => 3
```

However, if you are dead set on using ES6 to retrieve this value we can leverage the spread operator (which is an ES6 feature) to retrieve the value:

```
/**
 * Create new array with all values in `items` array. Call `pop` on this 
 * new array to return the last value from the new array.
 *
 * NOTE: if you're using ES6 it might be a good idea to run the code
 * through Babel or some other JavaScript transpiler if you need to
 * support older browsers (IE does not support the spread operator).
 */
const items = [1, 2, 3];
const lastItemInArray = [...items].pop(); // => 3
```

Answer (score 2):

## Update - October 2021 (Chrome 97+)

**[Proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-array-find-from-last) for `Array.prototype.findLast` and `Array.prototype.findLastIndex` is now on Stage 3!**

You can use it like this:

```js
const items = [
  { a: 1 },
  { b: 2 },
  { c: 3 },
];

const last_element = items.findLast((item) => true);
console.log(last_element);
```

Comment: This looks promising. But still doesn't support by Firefox. Do you have an idea how to mimic this with the existing ES6+ syntax? (With conditions like `item.is_active == 'yes'`)

Comment: Hi. Just can just do this `items.findLast((item) => item.is_active === 'yes');`

Comment: Yeah, I figured that. But the problem is, this isn't supported by Firefox and the method itself is relatively new so a bit older browsers won't support it. Seeking for something that would work on Firefox and legacy browsers. ES6+ is just fine.

Comment: This worked, `const activeKeys = items.map(item => item.is_active); const lastActiveIndex = activeKeys.lastIndexOf('yes')`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
console.log(items[items.length - 1]);
```