# What will be the output for this code? I think output should be orange Green

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

I'm solving this problem on one of the coding platform and I wonder if given answer is correct. Please refer to the code below:

What is the output of the following code?

```
var color= ["Orange", "Blue", "Green"];

color.push("Red");

console.log(color[0]+ " " +color[color.length-1]);
```

I think output for this code should be **Orange Green** as "Red" will join the array and color.length-1 will return green as the output but the correct answer given is ** "Orange Red**". What is logic behind this?

Comment: You appear to know that arrays are 0-index!? Do you know what the index of the last element is? **`...length - 1`**! No idea what is unclear about this.

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216013/get-the-last-item-in-an-array or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050345/selecting-last-element-in-javascript-array

Comment: in this example length is 4, your last element index is 3 so it makes perfect sense

Comment: The last element is at position `length-1`. This is because the array starts at position `0` instead of `1`. The final array has `4` elements, so `color.length` is `4`. The elements are: `color[0] = 'Orange'` and `color[1] = 'Blue'` and `color[2] ='Green'` and `color[3] = 'Red'`. While the length of the array is `4` the last element is `color[3]`. The element at `color[4]` does not exist because the length of the array is only 4, not 5.

Comment: Instead of asking at SO, [why not test](https://jsfiddle.net/mjxuhetk/) by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that the first output would be `orange` since the list colors has `orange` in the 0th index. However, once you push 'red' to the list it alters the list to look like this: `['orange', 'blue', 'green', 'red']` so now color[color.length-1] will be 'red'
by pushing something to the list you add it to the end of the list, changing the size of the list.

Comment: Thank you Jerry! Going to report the answer given on platform XD