# Extract last string from a sentence using node.js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to extract last string from a sentence.

`var output` is

```
[info] Sikuli vision engine loaded.
[info] Windows utilities loaded.
[info] VDictProxy loaded.
The arguments are:  ['E:/automation.sikuli/automation.py', '{"command":"sel_medi
a","value":"5X7_on_letter"},{"command":"sel_printer","value":"cutepdf"},{"comman
d":"sel_tray","value":"formsource"},{"command":"print","value":"print"}']
5X7_on_letter not Selected
```

From this How can I get the last `5X7_on_letter not Selected` only?

Comment: `output.split('\n');` and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216013/get-the-last-item-in-an-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
var lastLine = output.match(/.*$/)[0];
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/131659), [**regex101 playground**](http://regex101.com/r/yW9rY5).

Explanation: `/.*$/` pattern matches all the symbols preceding the end of the string except `newline` ones. This will essentially cover only the last line of that string.

A regex-free alternative is using `lastIndexOf` to get the position of the last EOL, then taking the rest of the string. Like this:

```
var lastLine = output.slice(output.lastIndexOf('\n') + 1);
```

Comment: am not getting using this

Comment: Sorry, what? You don't have the expected result, or you don't understand how it works?

Comment: actually that is not working ,-...the output string is the response.but using ur code it is not working i dont know

Comment: Where's this string (value of `output`) taken from? What happens if you just `output.match(/not Selected/)[0]` instead? And what exactly does *'not working'* mean - do you get an error, an empty string, or the whole string in `lastLine`?

Comment: You shouldn't have quotes around your regex. ```var lastLine = output.match(/.*$/)[0];```

Comment: sorry :-( ..sorry ].. i just console.log(output) it got the above string.actually that output returns an array when i use output =output.split("\n").ur answer is correct.But in my case i got the last string by output[output.length-1]