# Can we get last unselected value of jQuery Chosen plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am trying to get last  unselected value. I have tried many ways but that can give me last selected values (by using last index) not last unselected. Is there any way to do it?

```
$('#f_district').chosen().change( function(evt, params) {
    if(params.deselected)
    {            
        alert($(this).val());  // it returns null how I can get last unselect value? 
    }
    else
    {
        var arr=$(this).val();
        alert(arr[arr.length-1]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you get an array? If yes, `pop` method returns the last value.

Comment: yes I am getting the array ('a','b','c'), how I can get that which is last selected value? by index or anything else?
how pop method?

Comment: Check this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216013/get-the-last-item-in-an-array

Comment: yes its getting in selection mode but when unselect it gets null in val()

Comment: can you create a JSFIDDLE for this ?

Comment: can you please check it here?

Comment: @RahulGupta http://jsfiddle.net/zj62f/

Answer (score -1):

are you looking some thing like this http://jsfiddle.net/Z2PkZ/1/

```
var previous;

$(".chosen").one('focus', function () {
    // Store the current value on focus and on change
    previous = this.value;
}).change(function() {
    // Do something with the previous value after the change
     console.log(previous);

    // Make sure the previous value is updated
    previous = this.value;
});
```

Comment: it returns last position value not recent deselect value