# Get last item of array - Angular/JSON

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I'm retrieving data from my API using Angular and adding the returned data to `$scope.addresses` I can get the first item in the `array` returned and assign it to a `var firstAddress = $scope.addresses[0]` how can I get the last item in the `array` returned?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the last item in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216013/get-the-last-item-in-an-array)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var lastAddress = $scope.addresses[$scope.addresses.length - 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

the idea is to **reverse** with the function `reverse()` the array firstly and secondly get the first element
***example :***

```
aRray: any[] = ['noredine', 'bahri', 'maroc']; // =>  array 
newArray: any[] = this.aRray.reverse(); //  => [ 'maroc', 'bahri','noredine']
console.log(this.newArray[0]); // result => maroc
```