# How to get specific array from JSON object with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I am working with facebook JS SDK which returns user's information in JSON format. I know how to get the response like response.email which returns email address. But how to get an element from a nested array object? Example: user's education history may contain multiple arrays and each array will have an element such as "name" of "school". I want to get the element from the last array of an object.

This is a sample JSON I got:-

```
"education": [
{
  "school": {
    "id": "162285817180560",
    "name": "Jhenaidah** School"
  },
  "type": "H**hool",
  "year": {
    "id": "14404**5610606",
    "name": "2011"
  },
  "id": "855**14449421"
},
{
  "concentration": [
    {
      "id": "15158**968",
      "name": "Sof**ering"
    },
    {
      "id": "20179020**7859",
      "name": "Dig**ty"
    }
  ],
  "school": {
    "id": "10827**27428",
    "name": "Univer**g"
  },
  "type": "College",
  "id": "9885**826013"
},
{
  "concentration": [
    {
      "id": "108196**810",
      "name": "Science"
    }
  ],
  "school": {
    "id": "2772**996993",
    "name": "some COLLEGE NAME I WANT TO GET"
  },
  "type": "College",
  "year": {
    "id": "1388*****",
    "name": "2013"
  },
  "id": "8811215**16"
}]
```

Let's say I want to get `"name": "some COLLEGE NAME I WANT TO GET"` from the last array. How to do that with Javascript? I hope I could explain my problem. Thank you

Comment: Related: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Related: [Get the last item in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216013/get-the-last-item-in-an-array)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski thanks for your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [JsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/hsx7ep45/)

```
var json = '{}' // your data;

// convert to javascript object:
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

// get last item in array:
var last = obj.education[obj.education.length - 1].school.name;
// result: some COLLEGE NAME I WANT TO GET
```

Comment: the json I shared, was just a part of another json. how can I split it like you did in jsfiddle?

Comment: @MohammadJulfikar Create a Fork of the JsFiddle and update the JSON, then paste the link here, I will take a look! :-)

Comment: @MohammadJulfikar awesome! :-) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

If your json above was saved to an object called `json`, you could access the school name `"some COLLEGE NAME I WANT TO GET"` with the following:

```
json.education[2].school.name
```

Comment: that 'education' is inside an array

Comment: The syntax is similar. If your json object is the first element of an array named `arr`, you can access the school name like this:
    `arr[0].education[2].school.name`

Answer (score 2):

If you know where that element is, then you can just select it as already mentioned by calling

```
var obj = FACEBOOK_ACTION;
obj.education[2].school.name
```

If you want to select **specifically the last element**, then use something like this:

```
obj.education[ obj.education.length - 1 ].scool.name
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply. But I have a confusion. what is FACEBOOK_ACTION here?

Comment: Well it is where your JSON data is stored. I just picked a random variable name where it might be stored :) Where is your JSON stored right now, then I will rewrite my answer for you

Comment: Oh thank you. My json starts like this:- {
  "id": "9040**1539",
  "name": "Mohammad Julfikar Mahmud",
  "email": "itsm**ail.com",
  "birthday": "02/10/19**",
  "education": [
    {
      "school": {
        "id": "1622**0560",
        "name": "J***chool"
      },

Comment: But how is the variable called? How do you call that JSON?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. This is the response that facebook returns :/

Comment: I know, that is what Facebook returns. But how do you know, that facebook returns it? Where do you call it? Or are you just testing it on their SDK/Dev website?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137858/discussion-between-lumio-and-mohammad-julfikar).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if (myData.hasOwnProperty('merchant_id')) {
    // do something here
}
```

where JSON `myData` is:

```
{
    amount: "10.00",
    email: "someone@example.com",
    merchant_id: "123",
    mobile_no: "9874563210",
    order_id: "123456",
    passkey: "1234"
}
```

This is a simple example for your understanding. In your scenario of nested objects, loop over your JSON data and use `hasOwnProperty` to check if key `name` exists.