# How to get the last value from an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In my case I am having the following array:

```
$array = [[01], [01,02], [01,02,03], [01,02,03,04], [01,02,03,04,05], [01,02,03,04,05,06]];
```

So from above array, I need only the last array which contains

```
[01,02,03,04,05,06]
```

Comment: Don’t you think the information **in what language** you want this might be slightly important …? Please read actual tag descriptions! `get` does not fit here at all.

Comment: Actually this is in JS.

Comment: `last = arr[arr.length - 1];` or `last = arr.pop();` which will also remove the last from `arr`.

Comment: And how hard is it to type “javascript get last array item” 
or similar into google …? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216013/get-the-last-item-in-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you to get an idea of how it is done, I'm writing this answer using JS

```js
var myArray = [[01], [01,02], [01,02,03], [01,02,03,04], [01,02,03,04,05], [01,02,03,04,05,06]]

var lastElement = myArray[myArray.length - 1]

console.log(lastElement)
```