# Get the last element of a string in array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Example:

`var someArray = ["My Name is", "My is Name", "Name my is", "is Name my"]`

I want to print the last element of each string, so:

`output: is, Name, is, my`

I have no idea where I should start. My first thought was to split the array and print the last index, but I didn't succeed

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216013/get-the-last-item-in-an-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var someArray = ["My Name is", "My is Name", "Name my is", "is Name my"];
let result = someArray.map(v => {
  let temp = v.split(" ");
  return temp[temp.length-1];
})
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/RegExp) to match the last word.

```js
var someArray = ["My Name is", "My is Name", "Name my is", "is Name my"]
var result = someArray.map(item => item.match(/\w+$/)[0]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var someArray = ["My Name is", "My is Name", "Name my is", "is Name my"];
var lastElements = "";

someArray.forEach(str => {
  splitStr = str.split(" ");
  lastElements += splitStr[splitStr.length - 1] + ", ";
});

console.log('output: ', lastElements);

//Outputs output:  is, Name, is, my,
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple approach:

```
const someArray = ["My Name is", "My is Name", "Name my is", "is Name my"]

const output = someArray.map(str => str.split(' ').pop());

console.log(output);
```