# Get last item in array AngularJS

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to get the last item from an array in AngularJS and I tried already to get the last item using the method explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3216041/6653509

But I can't seem to get it working.

This is how it looks:

```
.test(ng-repeat="item in data[0]")
  p {{item['samenvatting hoofdmelding']}}
```

Now I tried it like this:

```
.test(ng-repeat="item in data[0]")
  p {{item[item['samenvatting hoofdmelding'].length-1]}}
```

But with no success

Comment: is item a two dimensional array? can you give a sample what item looks like?

Comment: Can you show how the array looks like ? - @Larsmanson

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one should work:

```
.test(ng-repeat="item in data[0]")   

p {{data[0][data[0].length - 1]['samenvatting hoofdmelding']}}
```

the thing is the last item of `data[0]` is `data[0][data[0].length - 1]`