# How to find last element of an array without modifying source array in Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, es2022

I have an array contains

```
const data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
```

how to find the last element, result should be 'd'

Comment: Your question is asking how too **find** the last element without modifying and you answer your own question in the question itself. Maybe rephrase your question so that it complements the description you wrote.

Comment: **To people answering with `pop`:** Notice the *"without modifying the source array"* part of the question. :-) `pop` modifies the source array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the last item in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216013/get-the-last-item-in-an-array)

Answer (score 18):

Using the function `slice` + destructuring assignment.

```js
const data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
      [last] = data.slice(-1);

console.log(last);
```

Comment: how is that different from my answer? even the destructuring is an overhead over a direct access with an index.

Comment: Fancier, I think!

Answer (score 12):

You could slice from the end (negative index) and get the item of the array.

```js
const data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

console.log(data.slice(-1)[0]);
```

Answer (score 12):

As per ES2022, You can use [Array.at()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) method which takes an integer value and returns the item at that index. Allowing for positive and negative integers. Negative integers count back from the last item in the array.

**Demo :**

```js
const data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

console.log(data.at(-1));
```

Comment: This, IMO, is the best solution because it gives the exact value of the last item in the array, not another array, and doesn't require a separate function.

Comment: I'm puzzled by why this is not more commonly found in code and suggested by refactoring tools and AI. Can anyone point out a drawback ore performance penalty to this? (apart from IE not getting the update)

Answer (score 7):

Back in the day, the PrototypeJS library added methods to arrays like `first` and `last`. So if you want an alternative to `data[data.length - 1]`, you could have a utility method in your standard toolkit:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "last", {
    value() {
        return this[this.length - 1];
    },
    enumerable: false, // (This is the default, you can leave it off if you like)
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

and then use that:

```
console.log(data.last()); // 'd'
```

There's [an active proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-array-last) to add this to JavaScript as well.

Live Example:

```js
// In the toolkit
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "last", {
    value() {
        return this[this.length - 1];
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
});

// Using it:

const data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
console.log(data.last());
```

It's important to use `defineProperty` to create any property you add to `Array.prototype` (or heaven forfend, `Object.prototype`) leaving off the `enumerable` flag (or setting it `false`, which is the default) so that what you're adding is non-enumerable (doesn't show up in `for-in` loops). (You usually shouldn't use `for-in` to loop through arrays — [do one of these things instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) — but...people do.) If you just did `Array.prototype.last = function() { /*...*/ };`, `last` would be enumerable.

Just be sure only to do this in your own app/page code, not code you write and distribute as a library. Modifying built-in prototypes (other than polyfilling), even using `defineProperty`, is usually a bad idea in libraries other people will use.

Comment: @Ele - I should have put that in the answer, shouldn't I? :-) Done now.

Comment: Using (almost) the same approach one even could write ... `Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, '-1', { get() { return this.slice(-1)[0]; } });` ... and then access any array's last item like ... `[9, 8, 7, 6, 5][-1]` ... which for the latter example does return `5`.

Comment: @PeterSeliger - LOL, quite true. :-) Side note: `last` is now the subject of a proposal: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-array-last

Answer (score 0):

The pop() and slice() both method are faster. You can use pop() method if you are fine with modifying the array. If you don't want to change the array, the slice() method can be used.

```js
let arrItems = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

console.time('using array length');
let lastItem = arrItems[arrItems.length - 1];
console.log(lastItem);
console.timeEnd('using array length');

console.time('using slice method');
let lastItem1 = arrItems.slice(-1)[0];
console.log(lastItem1);
console.timeEnd('using slice method');

console.time('using pop method');
let lastItem2 = arrItems.pop();
console.log(lastItem2);
console.timeEnd('using pop method');

//Output:

//d
//using array length: 0.200ms
//d
//using slice method: 0.175ms
//d
//using pop method: 0.012ms
```