# Get last element of a JSON array in TypeScript

Tags: json, typescript, angular6

I need to get the value of the "id" property of the last element in array of JSON objects. I can find each element by id but I also need to get the value of last "id" in the array of JSON objects. In the example below it is '3'. Thanks in advance!

```
let types: any[] =
    [
        {'id': '0', 'value': ''},
        { 'id': '1', 'value': '' },
        { 'id': '2', 'value': '' },
        { 'id': '3', 'value': '' },
    ]; 

let index = 0;
let indexNext = 1;
types.forEach((item) => { 
    if (item.id == index) { 
        item.value = 'Book';
        console.log(item.value); //Book
    }
    if (item.id == indexNext) { 
        item.value = 'Magazine';
        console.log(item.value); //Magazine
    }
})
```

Comment: How was this not closed as a dupe for 2 years? It was asked in 2010. [Get the last item in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216013/get-the-last-item-in-an-array)

Comment: @DanDascalescu Perhaps because ES2022 only became part of Typescript in Feb 2022?  https://www.infoworld.com/article/3647880/typescript-46-adds-control-flow-analysis-es2022-support.html  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript#Release_history - I say this because you were advocating `array.at(-1)` in comments below.

Comment: @JGFMK: the accepted answer still uses ES3. Regardless of the answer, the question is a blatant dupe.

Comment: @DanDascalescu I fear you may often find that due to SO tagging saying Typescript and not JavaScript as well.. I am glad the post was here anyway - I learnt something with the `array.at()` syntax! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`types[types.length - 1]` gives you the last element of `types`.

If you're calling forEach to do something with every item of the array and then do something different to the last one, the callback parameter to [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) gets passed an index (as the parameter after the item). So you could write `types.forEach((item, indexForItem) => { ... });` and then compare `indexForItem` to `types.length - 1` to see whether you're on the last one or not.

Comment: the index parameter did the trick as well as types[types.length -1] Thanks a lot! Here is the code: `types.forEach((item, indexForItem) => { 
    var t = types[types.length - 1];
    if (t.id == indexForItem) { 
        console.log('The last id is: ' + t.id); // The last id is: 3
    }
}); `

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`types[types.length - 1]['id']`

Comment: That's even shorter. Thanks @JGFMK!

Comment: @GGG: the shortest is now [array.at(-1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216013/get-the-last-item-in-an-array)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at - a better link. Solution was buried on second page (mentions ES2022). https://stackoverflow.com/a/71242045/495157