# How do I find the last element in an array with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to return the last element in an array or, if the array is empty it should return null. What am I doing wrong / what is the best way to do this?

Here's my code:

```
function lastElement(x, y, z) {
    if (lastElement.length < 1 || lastElement === undefined) {
         return null; 
    }
    else {
        return(lastElement[lastElement.length - 1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would `return lastElement.slice(-1)` suffice? --- Also why are you referencing `lastElement`? That's the function name. `x`, `y`, and `z` are never used.

Comment: looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216013/get-the-last-item-in-an-array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the last item in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216013/get-the-last-item-in-an-array)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a local variable which has a different name as the function, preferably a paramter and check if an array is handed over which has a length.

Then return the last item or `null`;

```js
function getLastElement(array) {
    return Array.isArray(array) && array.length
        ? array[array.length - 1]
        : null;
}

console.log(getLastElement());       // null
console.log(getLastElement([]));     // null
console.log(getLastElement([1]));    // 1
console.log(getLastElement([1, 2])); // 2
```

Answer (score 1):

`lastElement` is the name of your function.

You need to use array for this, Maybe this way:

```js
function lastElement(array) {
    if (array.length < 1 || array === undefined) {
         return null; 
    }
    else {
        return(array[array.length - 1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `at` method, the optional chaining and nullish coalescing operators, you can do:

```js
const lastElement = array => array?.at?.(-1) ?? null;

// demo
console.log(lastElement([1,2,3])); // 3
console.log(lastElement([])); // null
console.log(lastElement(42)); // null
console.log(lastElement()); // null
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a function for this you can just use the .length property.
Also if you don't care if its undefined (when the array is empty) you can remove the. || null

```js
let some_array = [1,2,3,4]
let last_element = some_array[some_array.length-1] || null
console.log(last_element)
```

If you where do really need this in a function

```js
let some_array = [1,2,3,4] 
function get_last(array){
  //if the array is empty return null
  return array[array.length-1] || null 
}
console.log(get_last(some_array))
console.log(get_last([]))
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for any custom function. You can use any of the following process.

```js
let arrItems = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

console.log('using array length');
let lastItem = arrItems[arrItems.length - 1];
console.log(lastItem);

console.log('using slice method');
let lastItem1 = arrItems.slice(-1)[0];
console.log(lastItem1);

console.log('using pop method');
let lastItem2 = arrItems.pop();
console.log(lastItem2);

//Output:

// using array length
// d
// using slice method
// d
// using pop method
// d
```

Comment: `pop()` mutates the original array, therefore it is not a getter.