# How to get the last element of array and save in variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to save the last element of an array which gets its values from a multiselect dropdown and looks like this for example with two elements:
[34, 33]

What I want to do know is to always get the last element inside it in this case the 33 and save it for further use in a variable. But for some reason personId2 is always all elements like this:
[34, 33]
But I want to have just the 34 if it is the only element or the 33 if it is the last element
.

this is the part where I am trying to get the last element:

```
let personId = 0
    let personersonId2 = 0
    this.personArray.push(this.form.controls.multiSelectBox.value)
    this.personArrayStaging = this.personArray[length]
   
    for(personId = 0; personId < this.personArray.length - 1; personId ++){
        personId2 = this.personArray[personId ]
    }
```

Comment: find length of array every time and then get the index+1 and save it to your variable like let len=(array.length);now its your last index of array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the last item in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216013/get-the-last-item-in-an-array)

Comment: @Reyno for some reason it gives me an error when I try to use at. It does not find it

Comment: @saliksaleem what do you mean exactly? I am not sure what to do from your example sorry

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the last element of the array, the simplest solution is to call `arr.at(-1)`

```
const arr = [11, 22, 33, 44];
const lastElement = arr.at(-1); // 44
```

Answer (score 0):

Can not follow the code, but if you want to grab the last element of an array all you need is calling `arr[arr.length-1]`. If you don't want to repeat it over and over, make it a function

```
lastElement = (arr) => arr[arr.length-1]


let x = lastElement([]) // x = undefined
let y = lastElement([1,2]) // y = 2 
let z = lastElement([3]) // z = 3
```

Comment: already tried this approach but the same problem

Comment: then you are doing something else wrong. above code simply takes last element from array, then we made assignment. btw, you should add additional checks for production code (e.g.  check if given argument is an `Array` or not )

Answer (score 0):

You can use `length-1`or the javascript function `pop()`. Importnat note: But pop will remove the last element from your array.

```js
let arr = ['hello','world'];
const last = arr.pop();
console.log(last);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is fixed now the problem was the push part in my personArray it should have been like this:
personArray = this.form.controls.MultiSelectBox.value