# d.split("+").at is not a function. (In 'd.split("+").at(-1)', 'd.split("+").at' is undefined) error in safari 14.1 running react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, macos, safari, babeljs

TypeError: d.split("+").at is not a function. (In 'd.split("+").at(-1)', 'd.split("+").at' is undefined)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5Twi.png)

while running react app on `safari 14.1` i come across this error , but on  safari latest versions and google chrome, react app is working fine.

i tried debugging the the error and i think it's from the bundle.js file, if not please correct me.

Comment: You need Safari 15.4 or higher to use `.at()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at#browser_compatibility, use `.pop()` or index using the length of the array `-1`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include some of your source code and show what you've tried and what you want to achieve. See [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at the [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at#browser_compatibility) of [`.at()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) you can see that Safari version 15.4. or higher is required for both desktop and mobile in order to use `.at()`.

Unfortunately, Babel doesn't seem to compile `.at()` down on lower Safari versions either.

[Babel Playground](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=safari%2014&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=3.21&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=NoRgNABATJDMC6A6AhgFwBQFoQEoDcQA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&modules=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.22.10&externalPlugins=&assumptions=%7B%7D)

I'd recommend to use an alternative syntax that produces the same result such as `array[array.length - 1]`, `array.pop()`, ...
This might be helpful to find a suitable workaround: [Get the last item in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216013/get-the-last-item-in-an-array)