# Converting string formula to mathematical formula in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

Hai all,

I am doing c#.NET application  to calculate different formulas and give result to user,users can enter any formula and each formula values are stored in database like this.

[image]

After saving like this i want to calculate the result.When calculating the result,application ask values for `variables`.But how can i calculate with this values.
Please help to retrieve each values from database and calculate the result.

Comment: You need to add more details about how the formulas are described, how is operator precedence defined (parenthesis)? What should the result of the above example be?

Comment: @Albin Sunnanbo:problem is that precedence not defined (parenthesis).Only save values are varible/constant and operator.Please look at image  uploaded.

Comment: Create a WebRequest, pass the entered formula as a query to Google and parse the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Shunting-yard algorithm to convert the expression to postfix notation or to ast directly. See this answer for nice explanation: [Equation (expression) parser with precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256/equation-expression-parser-with-precedence/47717#47717)

Comment: +1: You may want to add these useful links: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postfix_notation