# Need help in resolving Java String issues

Tags: java, android, string, function

I am developing a programmable calculator in android.I am getting user input in the form of charsequence which i then convert into string. But before i can put them in the stack **i must check whether the input is an integer or a sign.**

I am basically from a C++ background. So i am having issues finding the right functions to do the job. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256/equation-expression-parser-with-precedence

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Now i understand how to check whether the input is int or not. However in the next step when i determine that some input is not integer how can i check if that input is a +,-,* or / sign.

Answer (score 4):

Two possible solutions:

1. You can create a [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) that checks if your string is a number
2. You can try to extract its integer value using
   [`Integer.valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29), and catch the exception [[NumberFormatException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html)] thrown - if it is not a
   number.

The first is most likely to be more efficient then the second

Answer (score 0):

Don't allow the user to enter text and special characters in **Textbox(Edittext)**.When user enters the number in the textbox convert that number to integer as follows **Integer.parseInt(yourstring);**

Answer (score 0):

You need to us `Integer.parseInt` and catch the appropriate `NumberFormatException` if the user does not enter a number:

```
try
{
  // the String to int conversion happens here
  int i = Integer.parseInt(s.trim());

  // print out the value after the conversion
  System.out.println("int i = " + i);
}
catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
{
  System.out.println("NumberFormatException: " + nfe.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can match for the validaty of input with this regex through [+-]?\d*