# Convert Equation from One Language to Another

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have a task where I need to convert equations in one language (MATLAB) to another (C++) using Python. Everything is straightforward except the power operation. The equations are represented by Python strings.

For example, I want to convert

```
Eq = ((a+b)^2 + (c+d)^(1/2)) * e
```

to,

```
Eq = (pow((a+b),2) + pow(c+d, 1/2)) * e
```

I tried regular expression, but it does not seem to work because of nested parenthesis. Is there any good way to do this?

Comment: In C, `pow(c+d, 1/2)` is always 1. So it's not quite as simple as just changing operators.

Comment: Do you want to convert the first string to second string? Your question is not clear. I am close-voting it.

Comment: It has been covered many times why using regex to parse structured data is a bad idea. Usually people try it with [HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) so this is slightly novel. But it's still a bad idea.

Comment: This is the kind of task that [source-to-source compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler) are designed  to handle.

Comment: @thefourtheye yes I want to convert the first string to the second. I edited my question.

Comment: To expound on @rici's comment, `1/2` evaluates to `0` in C, you need to convert integer literals to floating point literals in expressions, as `1.0/2.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to solve this would be to use Abstract Syntax Tree of Python. We can get that using [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) module.

```
import ast, _ast

ops = {_ast.Mult: "*", _ast.Add: "+", _ast.BitXor: "pow", _ast.Div: "/"}

def rec(n):
    if isinstance(n, _ast.Expr):
        return rec(n.value)
    elif isinstance(n, _ast.BinOp):
        if isinstance(n.op, _ast.BitXor):
            return "{}({}, {})".format(ops[type(n.op)], rec(n.left),rec(n.right))
        else:
            return "({} {} {})".format(rec(n.left), ops[type(n.op)],rec(n.right))
    elif isinstance(n, _ast.Name):
        return n.id
    elif isinstance(n, _ast.Num):
        return n.n

print rec(ast.parse("(((a+b)^2) + ((c+d)^(1/2))) * e").body[0])
# ((pow((a + b), 2) + pow((c + d), (1 / 2))) * e)
```

**Note:** Since `^` means Binary XOR operation in Python, you need to enclose that expression with an extra parenthesis, like I have shown in the example.

First, we check if it is an expression, then we process its value. If it is a binary operation, we check of it is Bitwise XOR, in that case we return the result in a different format, otherwise we return the result like `left op right`. If the current item looks like a name, then we return its `id` or if it is a number we return the attribute `n`.

Comment: Thanks! I added `_ast.Sub` and `_ast.USub` for `-` operation and sign, and it works great!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows. Note: This is still a very primitive approach and I'd be careful about relying on it 100%:

```
import re

s = "Eq = ((a+b)^2 + (c+d)^(1/2)) * e"

>>> print re.sub(r'\(([^()\s]*)\)\^\(?([^()\s]*)\)?', 'pow(\\1,\\2)', s)
Eq = (pow(a+b,2) + pow(c+d,1/2)) * e
```

Comment: OP wants to convert to C++ using Python, not convert to Python using Python. `**` is not going to work in C++.

Comment: @rici, Sorry. My mistake. I have removed that part.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd do this with a simple tokeniser and parser rather than regular expressions. It's not [that hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256/equation-expression-parser-with-precedence) to write and will be more robust and readable than a regular expression based parser.