# Is there a standard C++ tool to parse arithmetic expressions?

Tags: c++

What I'm trying to do is described in the comment block immediately inside the function:

```
bool CalculusWizard::partitionEquation(const std::string & eq, std::string & eq1,
    std::string & eq2, CalcWizConsts::eqOps & oper)
{
    /* Given an equation eq, partion eq into 
       eq = eq1 oper eq2
       where oper is the operator with the lowest precedence, 
       e.g. eq = "x*sin(x)+x^2" --> eq1 = "x*sin(x)", oper = ADDITION, eq2 = "x^2".
       If there is no operator, e.g. eq = "x", then oper = NONE.
       The error checking is done in this function. If there is a syntactical error 
       in eq, then return false.
    */
    bool eqGood = true; 
    eq1.clear();
    eq2.clear();
    oper = CalcWizConsts::NONE;
    int netParans = 0;
    std::string::const_iterator it(eq.begin()), offend(eq.end());
    while (it != offend)
    {
        char thisChar(*it);
        char nextChar(((it+1) != offend) ? *(it+1) : '\0');         
        if (thisChar == '(')
        {
            if ()
            ++netParans;
        }
        else if (thisChar == ')')
        {
            if (isOp(nextChar))
            {

            }
            --netParans;
        }
        else if (CalcWizConsts::digMap.count(thisChar) == 1)
        {

        }
    }
    if (netParans != 0)
        eqGood = false;

    return eqGood;

}
```

You can ignore the gunk that I've started to write. I've just about given up. Time to see whether someone has already done what I'm trying to do.

The operators I have, in order of precedence, are `^`, `*`, `/`, `+` and `-`. The functions that might be in the equation are `x`, `sin(x)`, `cos(x)`, `e^x` and `log(x)` (although I want to be able to add more later). Is there any standard mechanism of doing what I'm trying to do?

Comment: What would the expected output of partitioning `x^2 + x + 1` be?  Also, are we to assume that the input is already syntactically valid? (For example, nothing like `x^^^5 ++ 2`)

Comment: I'm checking for syntactical validity along the way, the partitioning of x^2 + x + 1 would be eq1 = x^2 and eq2 = x + 1

Comment: -1 for an exceptionally meaningless question title

Comment: @GigaWatt Actually, that can be solved unambiguously. When you create a mathematical expression compiler it is useful to define, what is the direction of association of operators, which already are associative. For example, you can *assume* (for the sake of the algorithm), that a + b + c = (a + b) + c, what gives yuo unambiguous "partition" into (a + b) and c.

Comment: @user3681052, I've edited your title. Feel free to change it, but this should give a good idea of what a title should look like.

Answer (score 5):

What you mostly probably want to do is to break the expression into expression tree - in such form it is a lot easier to process.

To do that, first you need some kind of parser, which will break expression into tokens. Then you can use Reverse Polish Notation conversion algorithm to build an expression tree. [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) has a lot relevant informations.

In your example, the expression tree would look like the following:

```
x*sin(x)+x^2

     +
   /   \
  *     ^
 / \   / \
x sin x   2
   |
   x
```

With this tree you can easily process the whole expression in any way you want.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a [parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser) that can translate a string into a data structure that represents the expression, taking operator precedence into account.  Parsing is a broad topic and you'll need to do some reading, but the [Boost Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/) library is a decent way to write parsers in C++, and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256/equation-expression-parser-with-precedence) also provides some useful background (though it's not specific to C++).