# Turning a string that contains a equation into an integer

Tags: c++

I would like to be able to convert a string such as "(5+6)*6" and get the resulting integer from that equation. It is important that it starts out as a string.

Comment: Check this out : http://www.speqmath.com/tutorials/expression_parser_cpp/index.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equation (expression) parser with precedence?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256/equation-expression-parser-with-precedence)

Answer (score 3):

You can use library [fastmathparser](https://fastmathparser.codeplex.com/) for c++.
In link is example how use this library.

If you really want write alone this parser, I recomended use [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)