# Evaluating mathematical expression from a string and inserting it on stack

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, stack, expression

I'm trying to build an arbitrary precision calculator.
I represent numbers in linked lists (one node is a single digit), and I want to store them in a stack.
However, I can't seem to figure out how to break the mathematical expression received as a string apart while keeping the right mathematical operations order.

For example, if the inserted expression is `6*8-2+8-8*9/4`, I'll represent numbers as linked lists and insert them into a stack, and insert the operators into a different stack, and then I want to pop the arguments for each calculations and push the result again, and so on until I get the final result.

My question is, how can I implement this and still follow the mathematical operations order?

Comment: A common way to do this is to first convert the expression to [RPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) using Dijkstra's [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)

Comment: First, use standard library's shlex to tokenize, then come up with grammar and implement a parser. I find shift reduce parser the simplest to understand and implement. I did a toy project recently on this -- shreducers on github.

Comment: Please see this question and good replies. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256/equation-expression-parser-with-precedence

Answer (score 0):

you could try using `eval`?

```
eval("6*8-2+8-8*9/4")
```

This would give you `36`

EDIT:

If eval isn't feasible, maybe try `operator` to convert the string operators to mathematical ones:

```
import operator
operations = {
    '+' : operator.add,
    '-' : operator.sub,
    '*' : operator.mul,
    '/' : operator.div,
    '%' : operator.mod,
    '^' : operator.xor
}
```

Then maybe you could loop through the string and evaluate it that way?
(I'll have a think about the looping part now and edit my answer if I get anything good)

Comment: I wish. It's a college project and I'm required to do it exactly as i wrote it.

Comment: Ah fair enough, I'll have a think and update my answer if I come up with anything useful :)

Comment: Thank you kind sir!

Comment: Doing it this way is ok if you evaluate stuff in strict left-to-right order, but it gets tricky if you want to use the usual mathematical precedence rules and you need to handle parenthesized expressions.

Comment: @PM2Ring yeah I'm sure there is a better solution to my answer, I'm going to have a read through of the things you mentioned in your comment earlier, looks really interesting and useful to know! :)