# Validating brackets presence when some math logic found in String

Tags: java, string, parsing

At the moment I work with some logical and mathematical expressions given as a String. Unfortunately, there is a need to use brackets on expressions when using chars: **'&'** and **'|'** (used instead of **'||'**).

Valid expressions:

**`(x + 2) & (y * 4) | (i - 4)
(5 > 4) | (6y + 4)`**

Invalid expressions:

**`x + 2 & y * 4 | i - 4
5 > 4 | 6y + 4`**

I have tried to check String with RegEx, something like:

**`[)][ \t\n\r]*[&][ \t\n\r]*[(]`** makes sense.

The problem is: how to find all **'&'** and **'|'** chars and find presence of near brackets?

**Edit: I have a solution based on searching for index of those characters, then going in both ways and looking for brackets. Maybe I can make it in more simple way with RegEx?**

Comment: You need to find or implement a parser for your expression language.  Search for "parse expression".  Or if look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256/equation-expression-parser-with-precedence

Comment: does your string also contains **'||'**.

Comment: Note that parsing expressions using regexes is a bad idea.  Either you end up with a horribly complicated regex that supports a recursive expression grammar ... or you have edge cases (complicated expressions) that don't parse when they shoould or vice versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relatively simple solution:

1. split on `&` and `|`;
2. trim all sub-expressions;
3. check whether they all start with `(` and end with `)`.

---

**Snippet:**

```
String s = "(x + 2) & (y * 4) | (i - 4)";

boolean valid = Arrays.stream(s.split("[&|]"))
                      .map(String::trim)
                      .allMatch(p -> p.startsWith("(") && p.endsWith(")"));
```

If you need to address more complex scenarios than the ones presented in your question (nested expressions etc.), you'll need to write a parser.

Comment: This won't work if you have nested brackets.  (OK ... the OP didn't say he needed this, but I bet that some of his users will expect nested brackets to "just work".)

Comment: Yep, we use nested brackets. Also comments, variables, booleans... I need to start with something, next steps are on my own :)

Comment: Looks like you'll be writing a parser :)

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen this solution looks really nice, I need to adjust it because of comments possibility in the end/beginning of expression